# Show "Loading..." in dropdown box

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax

I'm running a database query to load a dropdownbox using jquery. Is there a way to display the words "Loading..." in the dropdownbox while the query is running?

Thanks.

Comment: FYI, when you're adding items to the dropdown after you've retrieved it, steer clear of manually adding each option to the list if the number of options is more than a trivial amount. You'll want to do a batch insert similar to:

var options = [];
var index = -1;

for (var item in items) {
  options[++index] = '<option value="';
  options[++index] = item;
  options[++index] = '">';
  options[++index] = items[item];
  options[++index] = '</option>';
}

options[++index] = '</select>';
$(ListBox).after(options.join(''));

Warning code isn't tested and probably won't work as is.

Comment: Ugh, the formatting isn't taking here, not real sure how to make it format properly. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down as a launching point for performance with a large number of options. Basically, you want to limit the amount of DOM manipulation you're doing. It's quicker to do one large insert into the DOM than to update it a large amount of times.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can add temporary item to your dropdown list while the ajax is running:

```
$('#myDropDown').prepend($('<option></option>').html('Loading...'));
```

Comment: Why call HTML method when you can simply do

$('#myDropDown').prepend('<option>Loading..</option>');

Looks easier to read IMHO.

Comment: I'm New In Programming, Can You Tell Me, How Can I do That With my Code ? (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42593871/ajax-combo-box-with-please-wait-label-for-loding-data)

Answer (score 9):

Let's call your drop down 'userChoice', you can write code like

```
$(document).ready(
    function()
    {

        //Before calling your ajax method, clear the select drop down.
        //and add a loading option.
        $('#userChoice')
            .children()
            .remove()
            .end()
            .append('<option value="">Loading...</option>');

        $.ajax(

                    //Load the userChoice as usual in success handler of your ajax call. 
                    success : function() { //Load #userChoice } 
              );


    }
);
```

Answer (score 2):

If there's nothing in there to begin with, just make that your default HTML and you've eliminated half of your jQuery.

```
<select>
  <option>Loading...</option>
</select>
```

And when your query has finished, just replace the single `option` with your results.

Comment: this is the sanest option (no pun intended) in my opinion :) +1

Answer (score 1):

add this before ajax post

```
$('#myDropDown').empty();
$('#myDropDown').append($('<option></option>').html('Loading...'));
```

then again on success dynamically append dropdown

```
$('#myDropDown').empty();
$('#myDropDown').append($('<option></option>').val("").html("Select"));
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                $('#myDropDown').append($('<option></option>').val(array[i].selectedvalue).html(array[i].selectedtext));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are running the query through an AJAX call, you can use something like the following to first clear the dropdown list and insert the loading message (in client-side Javascript):

```
var lb = document.getElementById ("myDropdownList");
lb.options.length = 0;
var newOpt = new Option("Loading...", "");
lb.options[0] = newOpt;
// Your jquery call here
...
```