# Ajax Combo box with `Please Wait` label For Loading Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

How Can I Have a `Please wait..` or `Loding...` label For Loding Data Time below of my Combo box?

I Want, When Switch Between Male And Female, see `Loading...` under Switch box
[image: Please see this Photo]

HTML

```
<body>
    <form>
      <select name="users" id="users">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" id="for-male" styl>Male</button>
      <button type="submit" id="for-female">Female</button>
    </form> <br>
    <div id="txtHint"><b>Person info will be listed here.</b>
    </div>
</body>
```

The javascript will look like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#users').on('change', function() {
    $('#for-male, #for-female').hide()
    var value = $(this).val()
    if(value == "1") {
        $('#for-male').show();
    } else {
        $('#for-female').show();
    }

  });
});
```

and the css will be

```
#for-male, #for-female{
  display:none;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show "Loading..." in dropdown box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1120920/show-loading-in-dropdown-box)

Comment: I'm New in Programming. Can You Edit with my code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  //save actual text
  var text = $('#test').html();
  
  $('#users').on('change', function() {
    $('#for-male, #for-female').hide()
    var value = $(this).val()
    if (value == "1") {
      $('#for-male').show();
    } else {
      $('#for-female').show();
    }
    //change text to loading
    $('#test').html('Loading...');
    
    //this is demo code for testing, here you will call your ajax function
    setTimeout(function(){
      //change back to orignal text
      $('#test').html(text);
    }, 1000);

  });

  
});
```

```css
#for-male, #for-female{
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <select name="users" id="users">
        <option value="">Select a person:</option>
        <option value="1">Male</option>
        <option value="2">Female</option>
      </select>
  <button type="submit" id="for-male" styl>Male</button>
  <button type="submit" id="for-female">Female</button>
 <br>
<div id="txtHint"><b id="test">Person info will be listed here.</b>
</div>
```

Comment: I Want, When Switch Between Male And Female, see `Loading...  `    in place of `Person info will be listed here.`, I Mean `Person info will be listed here.` Change to Loading....

Comment: I Want, When Switch Between Male And Female, see Loading... under Switch box

Comment: Ok wait i am updating my answer