# AJAX Cascading dropdown without updatepanel?

Tags: asp.net, jquery

I want to make a cascading dropdown list without using an UpdatePanel. I need tips for starting out this task. Currently,

1. I am using asp.net 2.0
2. Will I be able to parse JSON in VSS 2005 if I use JQuery ?
3. What is the recommended alternate for UpdatePanel in Visual Studio 2005 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend jquery.Create a webservice in your project and call the webservice from jquery and parse the json result on UI.

Check out this [link](http://aspdotnetcodebook.blogspot.com/2009/11/cascading-dropdownlist-using-jquery-and.html).

If you have any doubt let me know.

Comment: Thanks for the link santosh, I will have a look. Just one thing, Google had me confused as there are a lot of approached. Some suggest using Httphandlers others suggest webmethods,aspx pages etc. Would I be able to do all this while using VSS 2005 or is VSS 2008 necessary to use JQuery, JSON ?

Comment: I think the link you forwarded is using LINQ, I'd be using sql queries.

Comment: Damien:It does not matter...just replace the Linq query and write your own query.

Comment: Hey santosh I am having 'undefined' response from JQuery on IE 8, works good in firefox. Check my post here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4848617/message-from-webpage-undefined

Answer (score 3):

If you use web forms , an alternative way is to create PageMethods and call them from JavaScript and fill the select with jQuery.

Comment: Thanks Vasioky. I am using webforms. Do you have any example ?

Comment: At the moment I'm working on mvc project and I don't have any example but here an example how to use PageMethods http://aspalliance.com/1922 and here an example how to to populate dropdown http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down