# Populating One Select Box Based on the Selection in Another Select Box - JQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to populate one select box based on the selection made in the first select box. I've looked online, and found a lot of helpful information on hard-coded options, but I need my options to come from a query (like cfquery in coldfusion). I know that a cfquery is server-side, so I cannot include it in my jquery, but is there another option?

I was using the following example:

HTML:

```
<select id="counties">
    <option> </option>
    <option> somerset </option>
    <option> hertfordshire </option>
</select>

<select id="towns" disabled="true">
</select>
```

JS:

```
var countyTowns = [
    ["Bath", "Bristol"],
    ["Letchworth", "Hitchin"]
];

$("#counties").change(function() {
    var county = this.selectedIndex - 1;
    $("#towns").empty();
    if (county === -1) {
        $("#towns").attr("disabled", true);
    } else {
        var towns = countyTowns[county];
        for (var i = 0; i < towns.length; i++) {
            $("#towns").append($("<option></option>").text(towns[i]));
        }
        $("#towns").attr("disabled", false);
    }
});
```

What I would need is for towns to be dynamic, and able to be read from a database.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Best practice to populate drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)

Comment: @SaeedAnsari Link is outdated.

Comment: Maybe this library will help you? https://smarek.github.io/jquery-chained-selects/demo.html

Answer (score 2):

as you mentioned that : *towns to be dynamic, and able to be read from a database* you can get dynamic data by passing it with ajax.

**Ajax Get from controller** to read **from database based Country** which user has selected:

```
 <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
           $("#counties").on('change', function () {
                var selectedItem = $(this).val();
                var ddlStates = $("#towns"); // will be update after success ajax call
                var statesProgress = $("#states-loading-progress");
                statesProgress.show();
                $.ajax({     // get states/towns from db from controller
                    cache: false,
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "@(Url.RouteUrl("GetStatesByCountryId"))", 

                    data: { "countryId": selectedItem, "addSelectStateItem": "true" },
                    success: function (data) { 
                        ddlStates.html('');
                        $.each(data, function (id, option) {
                            ddlStates.append($('<option></option>').val(option.id).html(option.name)); 
                        });  // populating result 
                        statesProgress.hide(); // hide loader
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert('Failed to retrieve states.');
                        statesProgress.hide();
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    </script>
```

And on controller :

```
  public virtual IActionResult GetStatesByCountryId(string countryId, bool addSelectStateItem)
    {
        var model = _countryModelFactory.GetStatesByCountryId(countryId, addSelectStateItem);
        return Json(model);
    }
```

Then on **Data access layer** `_countryModelFactory.GetStatesByCountryId()`i get **towns/states** from db based the country/town user has selected.

**Update :**
It's the way i retrieving states/towns from db (dynamic country/towns) and populating them to `selectbox`in my code.

Comment: dear negative voter , I'll grateful if you mention why you see my answer as a negative? :)

Comment: This is really a great solution.

Comment: what is `statesProgress` - i assume this is a spinner, but would be nice to make this explicit :)

Comment: @Mohammad can you please re correct any missing parenthesis of this code. I am trying to use this trick. But it says its not structured well. I am a beginner, Thanks

Comment: @dax yes its a loader :)

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage hello , its my current code in my website so it's working , may you please inform which part you get error?

Comment: @PrageethLiyanage do you need my code on _countryModelFactory which i use to get data from db?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
 $("#counties").change(function() {
    if($(this).val()){
    $("#towns").attr('disabled',false);

   
  //var towns = countyTowns[county];
   // for (var i = 0; i < towns.length; i++) {
      //  $("#towns").append($("<option></option>").text(towns[i]));
   // }


      optionText = 'Premium'; 
      optionValue = 'premium'; 
  
      $('#towns').append('<option value="${optionValue}"> 
                                       ${optionText} 
                                  </option>'); 
    }
    else {
     $("#towns").attr('disabled',true);
     $("#towns").empty();
          
        
    }
  });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div id="div1"><h2>Let jQuery AJAX Change This Text</h2></div>
<select id="counties">
    <option> </option>
    <option> somerset </option>
    <option> hertfordshire </option>
</select>

<select id="towns" disabled="true">
</select>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are benefits and risks to using Lists Of Values coded into your page, as opposed to Lists collected using an AJAX Call.

AJAX Calls are good if the lists are especially long, or based on the Current User. Hardcoded lists can be good if the list is relatively simple/small and unlikely to change frequently.

To use a hardcoded list, use the following code:

```
var selectableValues = [
    {
    'title' : 'Words Starting With A' ,
    'values' : [
      'Apple' ,
      'Aardvark' ,
      'Alfalfa'
    ]
  } ,
  {
    'title' : 'Words Starting With B' ,
    'values' : [
      'Banana' ,
      'Beyond' ,
      'Belong'
    ]
  }
];

var $select_one = $select_two = false;

jQuery(function($){

  $select_one = $('#select_one');
  $select_two = $('#select_two');
  
    // Populate Select One
  $.each(selectableValues, function(k,v){
    $select_one.append('<option value="'+k+'">'+v.title+'</option>');
  });
  $('option:first',$select_one).text('Select...');
  $select_one.on('change',function(){
    populateSelectTwo(this.value);
  });

});

function populateSelectTwo( parentKey ){
  $('option',$select_two).remove();
  $select_two.append('<option value="">Select...</option>');
  $.each(selectableValues[parentKey].values, function(k,v){
    $select_two.append('<option value="'+k+'">'+v+'</option>');
  });
}
```

JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/lucanos/8fy4m7vp/