# Updating one select based on a choice on another select

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select inputs. I want the options on the second to depend on what's selected on the first.

EXAMPLE

**Select 1 - content list:**

- choice 1
- choice 2

**Select 2 - content list:**

If I select `choice 1` from the first:

- case A
- case B
- case C

If I select `choice 2` from the first:

- case X
- case Y
- case Z

Obviously both select inputs are in the same page!

I think I must use jQuery, but I don't know how.

Comment: Is dropdown 2 a "sub menu" of dropdown 1, or is it a separate dropdown? A Bootply of what you have would be helpful. Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: No..they are 2 separated dropdown menù, but they are in the same page. I want to update instantly the list of the second, depending on the choice I do in the first.

Comment: So the first is two options which toggle on or off the second dropdown menu? How is the click to the first dropdown stored? Again, a bootply of what you currently have would be amazing.

Comment: Like I wrote, I am a new one and I am not good using bootply. I try to do it and so probably you can understand what I mean! Thank you so much 4 your help. I'll try to crate a bootply example soon!!! :-)

Comment: I TRY TO USE BOOTPLY, SO HERE IT IS: http://www.bootply.com/120259 .

Comment: As I said, the example is really simple...2 dropdown menù in a page. I just would control the second using the choice of the first....So for example if the content of the first is "car-food-weather"..if i select CAR the second content list will be "honda-bmw-mercedes"..if i select food it will be "pasta-ham-potato"...and so on...

Comment: That is extremely helpful. Those are select boxes, not dropdowns, so it has nothing to do with bootstrap and everything to do with jquery only.

Comment: Aaaaaaah..ok. It's my fault using the incorrect word. Sorry. So you understand what I mean...and as I suppose, it's necessary using jquery. But..how to do it?! Can you help me?

Comment: There are many examples of this on StackOverflow. Here is one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861090/populating-one-select-box-based-on-the-selection-in-another-select-box-jquery

Comment: I corrected the question for you, and gave you a link to an example/duplicate question.

Comment: THAN YOU SO MUCH!!! It's hard to find the right thread when I don't know exactly how to explain the problem...Thank you again! :-)

Comment: No problem at all. This is an extremely large place, and jQuery is a very complex environment sometimes. It's hard to know how to phrase questions to get what you want, or even which library you're working with primarily. Welcome to StackOverflow!

Answer (score 0):

I just had some similar code to write, not sure if this may help you.

$(document).ready(function () {

```
$.DDCache = {
    init: function (DropDown) {
        this.cache = new Object(DropDown.clone());
    },
    FilterDropDown: function (DropDown, value, condition) {
        DropDown.empty();
        DropDown.append(this.cache.children().clone().toArray());
        DropDown.children("[" + value + "='" + condition + "']").remove();
    }
}

//init the cache for the select you want to filter

$.DDCache.init($("#Select2"));

$("#Select1").change(function () {
    $.DDCache.FilterDropDown($("#Select2"), "value", $("#Select1").val());
    });
```

});

Kind regards

:)

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that in you want something like this?

HTML:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span4 offset4">
      <form class="control-group" action="" method="post">
        <!-- DROPDOWN 1 - CHOICE SELECTION -->
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="document_type" class="form-control input-lg" id="Select1">
            <option value="casea">CHOICE 1</option>
            <option value="caseb">CHOICE 2</option>
            <option value="casec">CHOICE 3</option>
            <option value="cased">CHOICE 4</option>
            <option value="casee">CHOICE 5</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <!-- DROPDOWN 2 - LIST SELECTION-->
        <div class="form-group">
          <select name="document_type" class="form-control input-lg" id="Select2">
            <option value="casea">CASE A</option>
            <option value="caseb">CASE B</option>
            <option value="casec">CASE C</option>
            <option value="cased">CASE D</option>
            <option value="casee">CASE E</option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
</div>
```

and the script something like this?

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
     $.DDCache = {
        init: function (DropDown) {
        this.cache = new Object(DropDown.clone());
     },
     FilterDropDown: function (DropDown, value, condition) {
        DropDown.empty();
        DropDown.append(this.cache.children().clone().toArray());
        DropDown.children("[" + value + "!='" + condition + "']").remove();
     }
  }

  //init the cache for the select you want to filter

  $.DDCache.init($("#Select2"));

   $("#Select1").change(function () {
      $.DDCache.FilterDropDown($("#Select2"), "value", $("#Select1").val());
   });
});
```

just created a jsfiddle for you :)

http://jsfiddle.net/NBuSA/6/