# Populating second select list from the first and change action attr

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, arrays, drop-down-menu

I have a PHP array that populates the first select dropdown list so the user can select a occupation. After the occupation is selected, the second drop down list gets loaded with the job positions for that occupation using a JavaScript function.

Then I use jQuery to change the action attr of the form based on the value of the second drop down. But it returns null because the `<option></option>` are being loaded through the JavaScript. If I hard code the `<option></option>` in the select box, then it works.

Just as a note. I am not using a database. I'm using a php array to hold the data for the 2 drop down lists. The array is already loaded on the page as an include at the top of the php page.

Three part question here.

**First** - how do I resolve my issue with the action attr?

**Second** - is there a way to accomplish the populating the second drop down using a different method which may work better?

**Third** - And if it is ajax, how can it get the php array data without pulling it from the server again, since the array is already loaded into the php page?

Here's my code arrangement

**PHP Array**

```
$pages = array(

// Engineer
'Engineer' => array('pageTitle' => 'Engineer', 'subpages' => array(
    'Software Engineer' => 'Software',
    'Embedded Software Engineer' => 'Embedded Software',)),

// Analyst
'Analyst' => array('pageTitle' => 'Analyst', 'subpages' => array(
    'Systems-Analyst' => 'Systems',
    'Data-Analyst' => 'Data',))
);
```

**The Select and foreach loop**

```
echo '<form method="POST" action="?position=" id="menuform">
<select name="occupation" id="occupation">
<optgroup label="Select Occupation">
<option value="" selected disabled>Select Occupation</option>';
foreach ($pages as $filename => $value) {
    echo '
    <option value="'.$filename.'"'.((strpos($position, $filename) !== false) ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$filename.'</option>';
} // foreach pages


echo '
</optgroup>
</select>

<select name="position" id="position" onchange="this.form.submit()">

</select>
</form>
';
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var occupation = document.getElementById("occupation");
var position = document.getElementById("position");
onchange(); //Change options after page load
occupation.onchange = onchange; // change options when occupation is changed

function onchange() {
    <?php foreach ($pages as $filename => $value) {?>
        if (occupation.value == '<?php echo $filename; ?>') {
            option_html = "\n<? echo'<option selected disabled>Select Position</option>'; ?>\n";
            <?php if (isset($value ['subpages'])) { ?>
                <?php foreach ($value ['subpages'] as $subfilename => $subpageTitle) { ?>
                    option_html += "<? echo '<option value=\''.urlencode($subfilename).'\''.(($position == $subfilename) ? ' selected' : '').'>'.$subpageTitle.' '.$filename.'</option>'; ?>\n";
                <?php } ?>
            <?php } ?>
            position.innerHTML = option_html;
        }
    <?php } ?>
}
</script>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('#menuform').attr('action',$('#menuform').attr('action')+$('#position').val());
```

Answer (score 0):

**Regarding you first question, how to dynamically set form action, here is a test code:**

```
<?php

$pages = array(
  'Engineer' => array(
    'pageTitle' => 'Engineer',
    'subpages' => array(
      'Software Engineer' => 'Software',
      'Embedded Software Engineer' => 'Embedded Software',
    )
  ),
  'Analyst' => array(
    'pageTitle' => 'Analyst',
    'subpages' => array(
      'Systems-Analyst' => 'Systems',
      'Data-Analyst' => 'Data',
    )
  )
);
?>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4 id="form-action-shower">Form action: <span></span></h4>

<form method="POST" action="?position=" id="menuform">
  <select name="occupation" id="occupation">
    <optgroup label="Select Occupation">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Occupation</option><br />

      <?php foreach($pages as $occupation => $occData): ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $occupation ?>"><?php echo $occupation ?></option>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <select name="position" id="position">
    <optgroup label="Select Position">
      <option value="" selected disabled>Select Position</option><br />

      <?php foreach($pages as $occupation => $occData): ?>
        <?php foreach($occData['subpages'] as $key => $value): ?>
          <option value="<?php echo $key ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
        <?php endforeach ?>
      <?php endforeach ?>
    </optgroup>
  </select>

  <input type="submit" value="Click here to test form action">
</form>

<script>
  $('#position').change(function() {
    var form_action = '?position=' + $(this).val();
    $('#menuform').attr('action', form_action);
    $('#form-action-shower span').html(form_action);
  });
</script>
```

**Regarding your 2nd and 3rd question:**

You can use JSON to solve such issues. Here is an example I found: http://jsfiddle.net/YqLh8/

You can use PHP to have the array structure available in JS:

```
<?php
$pages = array(
  'Engineer' => array('pageTitle' => 'Engineer', 'subpages' => array(
    'Software Engineer' => 'Software',
    'Embedded Software Engineer' => 'Embedded Software',)
  ),
  'Analyst' => array('pageTitle' => 'Analyst', 'subpages' => array(
    'Systems-Analyst' => 'Systems',
    'Data-Analyst' => 'Data',)
  )
);

$json_pages = json_encode($pages);

echo "<script>var pages = $json_pages;</script>";
```

Which gives you a JS object like:

```
var pages = {
    "Engineer": {
        "pageTitle": "Engineer",
        "subpages": {
            "Software Engineer": "Software",
            "Embedded Software Engineer": "Embedded Software"
        }
    },
    "Analyst": {
        "pageTitle": "Analyst",
        "subpages": {
            "Systems-Analyst": "Systems",
            "Data-Analyst": "Data"
        }
    }
}
```

Then use JS to handle the on change events.

Comment: I don't see how this resolves the issue of the action attr of the form? The jSON is still doing same thing as the JavaSCript which is dynamically populating the select options. So whether I do it with JS or JSON, the action attr of the form will still get a null value based on the value of the second selected option. The object is to get the value of the second drop down to populate the action attr of the form. How does JSON help with that compared to what I already have?

Comment: thank you. How would you go about coding the JS to handle the on change event?

Comment: As I previously mentioned, a very good example is here: http://jsfiddle.net/YqLh8/. Also this url has the solution already: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5861090/populating-one-select-box-based-on-the-selection-in-another-select-box-jquery

Comment: thanks I already went back to your first jsfiddle example. Can't quite make it work with the jquery he used at the bottom of his example. I'll check out this other question.