# Populating a <select> With Values From a String List

Tags: jquery, ajax, regex, list, populate

I have a string list to be used with the [AccuWeather](http://accuweather.com/) API that is named `WeatherLocationDatabase.txt` and looks a bit like this:

```
CityName="Aachen, DE" Location="EUR|DE|GM011|AACHEN" Country="Germany"
CityName="Aalborg, DK" Location="EUR|DK|DA007|AALBORG" Country="Denmark"
CityName="Aalesund, NO" Location="EUR|NO|NO007|AALESUND" Country="Norway"
CityName="Aare, SE" Location="EUR|SE|SW006|AARE" Country="Sweden"
CityName="Aarhus, DK" Location="EUR|DK|DA001|AARHUS" Country="Denmark"
CityName="Aba, NG" Location="AFR|NG|NI008|ABA" Country="Nigeria"
CityName="Abadan, IR" Location="MEA|IR|IR016|ABADAN" Country="Iran"
CityName="Abakan, RU" Location="ASI|RU|RS033|ABAKAN" Country="Russia"
CityName="Abbotsford, CA" Location="NAM|CA|BC|ABBOTSFORD" Country="Canada"
CityName="Abeokuta, NG" Location="AFR|NG|NI000|ABEOKUTA" Country="Nigeria"
CityName="Aberdeen, UK" Location="EUR|UK|UK002|ABERDEEN" Country="United Kingdom"
CityName="Abidjan, CI" Location="AFR|CI|IV002|ABIDJAN" Country="Ivory Coast"
...
```

Is there any way to use AJAX to populate a `<select>` that should look like this using jQuery?

```
<select>
    <option value="CityName">CityName</option>
    <option value="CityName">CityName</option>
    <option value="CityName">CityName</option>
    <option value="CityName">CityName</option>
    ...
</select>
```

Comment: If only that list was in XML.

Comment: sure,

just look at this example from a [previous question.][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down

Comment: That question refers to well formed JSON. This guy looks like he has a comma separated list. Can you format this text file to prep it? Or is it the output from something else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With that text file you can use jQuery and make:

```
$.get('WeatherLocationDatabase.txt', function(text){
  var markup = "",
      i, item,
      data = text.split(/CityName="(.+)"\sLocation="(.*)"\sCountry="(.*)"\s?/mg).filter(function(e){return e});
  for( i = 0; item = data[i]; i+=3){
    // no need to specify value if equals to inner text.
    markup += "<option>" + item + "</option>";
    // you could break if data[i+1] or data[i+2] changes
  }
  $("#someSelectID").append(markup);
});
```

Explained `var data`:
I split through RegEx to match CityName, Location and Country value, and then I remove the empty strings indexes generated by the RegEx split with the filter hack. At that moment, data should look like:

```
["Aachen, DE", "EUR|DE|GM011|AACHEN", "Germany", "Aalborg, DK", "EUR|DK|DA007|AALBORG", "Denmark", "Aalesund, NO", "EUR|NO|NO007|AALESUND", "Norway", "Aare, SE", "EUR|SE|SW006|AARE", "Sweden", "Aarhus, DK", "EUR|DK|DA001|AARHUS", "Denmark", "Aba, NG", "AFR|NG|NI008|ABA", "Nigeria", "Abadan, IR", "MEA|IR|IR016|ABADAN", "Iran", "Abakan, RU", "ASI|RU|RS033|ABAKAN", "Russia", "Abbotsford, CA", "NAM|CA|BC|ABBOTSFORD", "Canada", "Abeokuta, NG", "AFR|NG|NI000|ABEOKUTA", "Nigeria", "Aberdeen, UK", "EUR|UK|UK002|ABERDEEN", "United Kingdom", "Abidjan, CI", "AFR|CI|IV002|ABIDJAN", "Ivory Coast"]
```

Which is basically: `[CityName1, Location1, Country1, CityName2, Location2, Country2, ..., CityNameN, LocationN, CountryN]` where N is line number.

Then I iterate every 3 items (because there are 3 properties)

Hope this helps.