# Combo box populated by Json

Tags: javascript, json, combobox

I am looking to populate a combo box with a Json file that is representing the file contents of a folder in a directory. I have snippets of code but its obviously not working and I am unsure how to go about implementing it correctly.

My Json code i want to populate the combo box looks like this:

```
["xml/cdcatalog.xml","xml/equip.xml"]
```

And this is the script i have embedded into the HTML page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#list1").jCombo(function() {
        $.getJSON('Jsontest.php?q=' + escape($('#list1').val()), function(data) {
            if ($("#list1").val() > 0) {
                alert("You chose " + $("#list1").val());
            }

        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This looks like code to get the jSon file, not populate the combobox.

Comment: How would i go about putting the Json file i requested into the combobox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
   $.getJSON("Jsontest.php", function(result) { 
       var options = $("#list1"); 
       $.each(result, function(item) { 
           options.append($("<option />").val(item).text(item)); 
       }); 
   }); 
});
```

Code taken from this answer:

[jQuery: Best practice to populate drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)