# populate dropdown list using jquery load event

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

I want to populate dropdown value from mysql table.I used load event
 in html page,but i don't know this code doesn't work.

**HTML PAGE**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("button").click(function(){
        $("#select1").load("se2.php");
      });
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>

    <select id="select1"></select>
    <button>Get External Content</button>

    </body>
    </html>
```

**se2.php**

```
 <?php
    $dbhandle = mysql_connect("localhost","root","") 
     or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
    $selected = mysql_select_db("student",$dbhandle) 
      or die("Could not select examples");
    $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT column1 FROM information");
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
   if($row['column1']!=NULL)
    {
    echo "<option value='$row[column1]'>$row[column1]</option>";
    }
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

change this

```
 <select id="select1"></select>
```

to this

```
<div id="select1"></div>
```

and add the select tags to the php

```
 $result1 = mysql_query("SELECT column1 FROM information");
echo "<select>";
     while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
    {
   if($row['column1']!=NULL)
    {
    echo "<option value='$row[column1]'>$row[column1]</option>";
    }
    }
echo "</select>";
```

and give the button an id

```
<button id="button">Get External Content</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do the logic in the front end using *jquery*, you can follow this example :

[jQuery: Best practice to populate drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)

This way you can return your php array using `json_encode()` and in you jquery function you access it as an object, like in the above example.

Answer (score 0):

In `HTML` instead of including `<select>` try this,

```
<div id="select1"></div>
```

And in `php` try this,

```
echo "<select>";
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result1))
{
   if($row['column1']!=NULL)
   {
     echo "<option value='$row[column1]'>$row[column1]</option>";
   }
}
echo "</select>";
```

Comment: is your jquery triggered ? try an `alert` inside `("button").click()`

Comment: do u have any other solution?

Comment: are u getting any error ? see if you are getting the response from the `php`

Comment: i got this code from w3schools.com link is here: "http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_ajax_load"

Comment: so what ? just try to print the values on ur php. run ur php file separately and see if you are getting the `select` box

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/18610/discussion-between-deepak-and-vinus-patel)