# Populate Combobox with ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax

Hi I am trying to populate a combobox using ajax, but I cant get it work. This is my code, I get the data from a Servlet.

```
 $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     url: "../../sListarProvincia",
     data: dataString,

     success: function (data) {
         $("#cboProvincia").append(data);
     },
     error: function (data) {
         alert("ocurrio un error");
     }
 });
```

Here is the code on my Servlet.

```
    try {
        /* TODO output your page here. You may use following sample code. */
        String IdDepartamento = request.getParameter("IdDepartamento").toString();
        List<Ubigeo> lisUbigeo = UbigeoCOM.ListarProvincias(IdDepartamento);

        String html="";
        for(int i=0;i<lisUbigeo.size();i++)
        {
            html = html + "<option value="+lisUbigeo.get(i).getIdUbigeo()+">"+ lisUbigeo.get(i).getNombre()+"</option>";

        }

        out.println(html);
```

My html:

```
<select style="float:left" id="cboProvincia" class="combobox" name="cboDepartamento">
</select>
```

Comment: Try `$("#cboProvincia").html(data);`.

Comment: first you need to give us which is the data type that you are receiving in your ajax and second if the data it's a html specified in the datatype property of your ajax

Comment: take a look to the edit

Comment: Please have a look at this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/818611/1577396).

Comment: what happens when your data it's appended? did you check your the dom to see how your data it's interpreted? also would be nice to know the headers

Comment: What is your `#cboProvincia` element? What you get when `alert(data);`?

Comment: data gives me a list of options <option></option> . see my edit

Comment: What exactly is not working? Does the success callback ever fire? This needs basic debugging first.

Comment: What does dataString contain?

Comment: FINALLY IT WORKED. I WAS USING BOOTSTRAP COMBOBOX, IT SEEMS IT DOESNT WORK WITH AJAX. I REMOVED "CLASS=COMBOBOX", AND IT WORKED, THANKS TO ALL OF YOU

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- If your `select` element has the ID `cboProvincia` in view source,
- If your `success` function fired,
- If your `data` is something to `<option>...</option>`,

Then this code must works correctly:

```
$("#cboProvincia").html(data);
```

Comment: Agreed, I was using boostrap combobox, and it seems it doesnt work with ajax.