# How to populate struts 2 ui select tag by json returned list using jquery?

Tags: jquery, struts2, struts, struts2-jquery, struts2-json-plugin

```
//struts.xml
    <package name="ajax" namespace="/" extends="struts-default,json-default">
        <action name="CheckUserAction" class="com.controller.ajax.AjaxAction">
            <result type="json">
            <param name="root">jsonData</param>
            </result>
        </action>
    </package>



    //Action Class
public class AjaxAction extends ActionSupport {
private String capacity;
private String greeting;
private List<String> countryList;
private Map<String, Object> jsonData;
public String execute() throws Exception {
    jsonData = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    greeting = "HI " + "AMIT";
    countryList = new ArrayList<String>();
    countryList.add("US");
    countryList.add("UK");
    countryList.add("Russia");
    jsonData.put("capacity", this.getCapacity());
    jsonData.put("countryList", countryList);
    jsonData.put("countryMap", countryMap);
    jsonData.put("greeting", greeting);
    return SUCCESS;
}
//Getter and setters
```

}

```
//Script
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#capacity").change(function() {
            var capacity = $("#capacity").val();
            $.getJSON('CheckUserAction.action', {
                capacity : capacity
            }, function(data) {
                $('#abc').append('<br>' + data.capacity);
                $('#abc').append('<br>' + data.countryList);
                $('#xyz').attr('value', data.greeting);
                $('#pqr').attr('list', data.countryList);
            });
            return false;
        });
    });





//JSP code
<table border="0">

        <tr>
            <td><s:label for="capacity" value="Capacity" /></td>
            <td><s:textfield name="capacity" placeholder="100" id="capacity"
                    value="abc"></s:textfield></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><s:label for="dynamic" value="Ajax" /></td>
            <td><s:textfield name="dynamic" value="learning" id="xyz"></s:textfield></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><s:label for="flightId" value="Flights" /></td>
            <td><s:select list="#{'1':'1' }" name="fightId" id="pqr"></s:select></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="abc">Initial</div>
```

I want to populate list(id:pqr) with json returned list countryList, i am able to change attribute  value of textfield(id:xyz),i also appended it to div(id:abc) but i am not able to change attribute list of struts select tag.
Is it has something to do with how struts tag are populated in HTML.

Also i am not using struts-jquery plugin nor dojo plugin.
Thanks

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/815103/1700321.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of data you are receiving in data.countryList? Can u post that data? I hope there is no attr property named **list** for dropdown. List property provided by Struts. You can compose the data for dropdown like

```
<option value="1">India</option>
<option value="2">United States</option>
<option value="3">United Kingdom</option>
```

and if you are sending new list you can do fill the countryList like,

```
$('#pqr').html(composed_country_list);
```

Else you are updating counrty means you can append the data to dropdown like,

```
$('#pqr').append(composed_country_list);
```

Let me know if this helps..

Answer (score 0):

The following code worked for me

```
     //JSP
    <s:select list="{}" name="fightId" id="pqr"></s:select>
```

Script File

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#capacity").change(function() {
        var capacity = $("#capacity").val();
        $.getJSON('CheckUserAction.action', {
            capacity : capacity
        }, function(data) {

            countryListItem = data.countryList;
        });
        return false;
    });
});       




    var pqr = $('#pqr');
    pqr.find('option').remove();
    pqr.append('<option value=-1>--Select--</option>');
     for(var i = 0; i < countryListItem .length; i++) {
            var opt = document.createElement('option');
            opt.innerHTML = countryListItem [i];
            opt.value = countryListItem [i];
            pqr.append(opt);

        }
```

Used javascript to populate the list by creating option attribute.
The struts select tag actually generates this kind of HTML internally.