# How to use a modelAttribute value in Jquery for Select box

Tags: java, jquery, spring, spring-mvc, select

I have a Map fetched from a database and I want to use the data to populate Select box. The Map is added to the model using sellerCodeList

In Spring it is simple:

```
<form:select path="orderDetails[0].SellerItemCode" items="${sellerCodeList}">
</form:select>
```

But I want to use the same in a Jquery function which builds up my select box. (*Reason: I have a table with dynamic rows and each row has a select box as one of the element*)

When I use the following I start getting error/exception

```
$("#poFields").append('<tr valign="top"><td>
<form:select path="orderDetails['+rowNum+'].SellerItemCode" items="${sellerCodeList}">
</form:select>');
```

This throws an exception

I see on SO that there is a way to iterate over the sellerCodeList and feed to options as per the following [Dropdown link from SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)

I am not good with JSON stuff though ;-)

Can someone please help

Comment: you cannot render spring tags or elements in jquery, spring tags are processed while rendering the jsp.

Comment: yeah .. I realised that .. Is there an alternative way to populate the dropdown ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to "print" your items into JS so that your JS code has access to them. Something like this:

```
<script>
    var sellerCodes = {};
    <c:forEach items="${sellerCodeList}" var="entry">
        sellerCodes['${entry.key}'] = '${entry.value}';
    </c:forEach>
    // you can now use sellerCodes in your JS code as a map.
</script>
```

Comment: The sellerCodeList is a map containing a database Key, value pair. I need both of them. Also, could you please advise the way to use sellerCodeListJs..Thanks

Comment: How do I feed this to the Select box options ? and if I have to see if there is anything previously selected .. can I do something like selected=${someVar}

Comment: @ike_love.. Thanks for the answers .. I used it partially to get what I wanted...<select name="orderDetails['+rowCreater+'].SellerItemCode" ><c:forEach items="${sellerCodeList}" var="entry"><option value="${entry.key}">${entry.value}</option></c:forEach></select>