# connecting several select boxes

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is there a easy way to have something like 3 select boxes where the previous one sets the options for the next one

like if the first select is `[clothing, food, countries]`

choosing food, will have in the 2nd select `[cheese, meat, fruits]`

and choosing fruits will have the last select as `[apples, bananas, oranges]`

also need to take into account that select data could be dynamic and comes from a server (before or during the selection)

the ways I thought of doing this are:

1. get all the data upfront, in some kind of json or other structure, and everytime a select is chosen, take the corresponding data. This could work for static data, but not for ajaxed data
2. everytime a select is chosen, get the data for its value. This could work but also requires manual js handling

Is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: you can create *all* possible selects, and then hide/show what you need

Comment: But if your data is dynamic, I think you have 2 good solution : 

The first, when you select a row, you load with ajax the next select. This is if your values change often. Like : select N°1 : [clothing, food, countries] => a user select an option => you ask via ajax the possibilities for the next select => you show select N°2.

Or the second, the easier just load all the form options onload of the page, or after a certain action and create all the structure by showing/hiding selects based on what you selected.

Dunno if I'm clear enough ^^

Comment: The option one I don't think it is a good practice, if you have many options it can cause a performance problem.
I'd do the second one, it is more performatic and clean.
To populate the combos easily, take a look here, if you are able to use jquery: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down