# Jquery: load() function not loading options in select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to load the option tags generated by back-end into my select tag when changes are made to either of 2 fields.

Here is the code for front end:

```
<select id="Events"> </select>
```

and this is the jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#Dept").on('change', function() {
        var dept = $("#Dept").val();
        var isTech = $(".isTech").val();
        $("#Events").load("/assets/scripts/Events.php?dept=" + dept + "&istech=" + isTech);
    });
    $(".isTech").on('change', function() {
        var dept = $("#Dept").val();
        var isTech = $(".isTech").val();
        $("#Events").load("/assets/scripts/Events.php?dept=" + dept + "&istech=" + isTech);
    });
});
```

This is not loading any tags, though I checked via URL and the back end is producing required output of option tag(s):

```
 <option value="56">spray ball</option>
```

I have checked the back-end and it is generating the appropriate option tags! it's just that these option tags are not loaded in the select tag.

Thanks for the help

Comment: you may want to check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down

Answer (score -1):

You can't load an ajax result into a select box itself. Try this below.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#Dept").on('change', function(){
    var dept = $("#Dept").val();
    var isTech = $(".isTech").val();

    $.get("/assets/scripts/Events.php?dept="+dept+"&istech="+isTech, function(response){ 
        $('#Events').html(response);
    });
  });

  $(".isTech").on('change', function(){
    var dept = $("#Dept").val();
    var isTech = $(".isTech").val();

    $.get("/assets/scripts/Events.php?dept="+dept+"&istech="+isTech, function(response){ 
      $('#Events').html(response);
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: Down-voter, would you mind to share your ideas why it is not the solution?