# Conditionally add selected attribute when building a dropdown with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm building a select dropdown, with the following function:

```
        $.each(data,function(key, value) {
            $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
        });
```

Here I copy a sample of my origin data:

```
231:"Building"
232:"Trusting"
234:"Engineering"
235:"(*)Monitoring"
236:"Managing"
```

When building it, I want to:

1. Mark the option that begins with '(*)' as selected, so I need to
   conditionally add the attr 'selected' to the option.
2. Remove the '(*)' from the value shown.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down

Comment: You can simply check whether '(*)' contains in your value, replace it with the empty string show it as selected.

Comment: @SumitGulati OK, the problem is that I don't know how to write it in jquery...

Comment: @Capiedge Its normal if - else. nfn-neil posted the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `.find` to figure out if the string starts with `'(*)'` then add `selected` to the end of the option and use slice to remove the `'(*)'`.

```js
data = {
  231:"Building",
  232:"Trusting",
  234:"Engineering",
  235:"(*)Monitoring",
  236:"Managing"
}
$select = $("#select");
from = '(*)';
$.each(data,function(key, value) {
  if (value.indexOf(from) == 0) {
    $select.append('<option value=' + key + ' selected>' + value.slice(from.length) + '</option>');
  } else {
    $select.append('<option value=' + key + '>' + value + '</option>');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select"></select>
```