# Populate dropdown values from a array jquery?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm trying to populate a dropdown values using jquery.

```
 <select class="browser-default" id="autopopulate" name="autopopulate">

  </select>
```

I'm populating the names using this

```
var names = ['a','b','c']

        for(let i=0;i<=names.length - 1;i++){
              let d = names[i]; 
              
              $("#autopopulate")
                  .append($("<option></option>")
                  .attr("value" ,d)
                  .text(d));
                }
```

How to append values to existing names

```
 var values = ['ab','bc','df']
```

For name `'a'` - value is `'ab'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [jQuery: Best practice to populate drop down?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down)

Comment: How do you know which value goes with which name? Position in array?  Then just set the value to `values[i]`.

Comment: Same as `names` - `'a' - 'ab'`

Comment: "Same as `names`" doesn't answer the question, but I'm guessing my assumption of position in array was correct. So `.attr("value", values[i])`.

Comment: Sorry, Yes position in array.