# Rails form - change select options based on another selected option through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am looking for a way to change the options in a rails form.select field through JavaScript based on the selected option for another select field.

The way I was trying to do this before was by using two separate fields with the same object and different sets of options, like so:

```
<%= form_with(model: my_model) do |form| %>

  <div class="form-floating" id="input">
    <%= form.select :input, ['a', 'b'], { }, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= form.label :input %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-floating" id="output1">
    <%= form.select :output, ['c', 'd'], { }, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= form.label :output %>
  </div>

  <div class="form-floating" id="output2">
    <%= form.select :output, ['e', 'f'], { }, class: "form-control" %>
    <%= form.label :output %>
  </div>

  <script>
    function onChange() {
      var selected = $('#input option:selected').text()
      if (selected == 'a') {
        $('#output1').show()
        $('#output2').hide()
      }
      if (selected == 'b') {
        $('#output1').hide()
        $('#output2').show()
      }
    }

    $('#input').change(onChange)
    $(window).on("turbolinks:load", onChange)
  </script>

  <%= form.submit class: "btn" %>
<% end %>
```

The problem with this method is that the :output field is created twice and only the last one (with id="output2") is submitted, so I'm now looking for a way to change the select options in the onChange() method for a single output form.select field.

Any help with this issue or an alternative solution would be greatly appreciated, cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved the problem, posting it here for anyone else having this problem.
Basically I abandoned the rails form helper in favour of building up the html string using  tags, something like this:

```
function replaceHTML() {
    var newHTML = '<select class="form-control" name="output" id="output">'

    var selection = $('#input option:selected').text()
    var options = selection == 'a' ? ['c', 'd'] : ['e', 'f']
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
      newHTML += '<option value=' + options[i] + '>' + options[i] + '</option>'
    }

    newHTML += '</select><label for="output">Output</label>'
    $('#output').html(newHTML)
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer: Use `$('#output-')prop('disabled', true);` instead of `.hide()`.**

**Long answer:**

According to the [JQuery docs](https://api.jquery.com/hide/), `.hide()` doesn't actually disable the input, it just hides it with CSS. Same with `.show()` it [looks like](https://api.jquery.com/show/). So you need to be using a different method for this. More on that in a second.

Second, the reason that only the second select box is being sent through, `output2`, is probably because they are both set up to be `<%= form.select :output %>`. According to the [Rails docs](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/v5.0/form_helpers.html), under the hood, Rails is setting both of these inputs up like this:

```html
<select name="output"></select>
```

Since you have two select boxes with the same `name` attribute, they're overwriting each other. This is again because you're using `.hide()` and `.show()`, so they're not actually being disabled.

I think this would work in your scenario. Try using `$("output").prop('disabled', true);` like so:

```js
  function onChange() {
      var selected = $('#input option:selected').text()
      if (selected == 'a') {
        $('#output1').show()
        $('#output2').prop('disabled', true);
      }
      if (selected == 'b') {
        $('#output1').prop('disabled', true);
        $('#output2').show()
      }
    }
```

If you're using JQuery Version < 1.5, you can use `$("input").attr('disabled','disabled');` according to this [Stack Overflow Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1414365/disable-enable-an-input-with-jquery).

Comment: Hey thanks for the response, unfortunately disabling the field doesn't seem to be working, just keeps submitting the selection from output2. Was thinking there was a way to have only one output select field, and populate the list of options from the JavaScript code, any ideas on how this can be done?

Comment: Hmm. You could try deciding which one you want to be defaulted, and then when the page loads, just auto-disable the other one through JS, and only re-enable it when you select a certain option. And then disable/re-enable when things change like normal.

Comment: For populating the select box through JQuery, that can get pretty tricky. It looks like [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815103/jquery-best-practice-to-populate-drop-down) does it. But, the first plan of trying to manage two select boxes that you disable/enable might be the best practice - it would definitely be the most readable when you look at the code 6 months from now lol

Comment: Yeah in the original method it calls onChange() on "turbolinks:load", tried a few iterations of setting the 'disabled' property to true and false but doesn't seem to affect the submitted variable.