# Single quotes in string with jQuery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping

I have run into a problem where the user enters data and if there are single quotes at all, the script errors out.

What's the best way to handle single quotes that users enter so it doesn't interfere with the jquery/javascript?

UPDATE:

I'm sending it through ajax to a database. here is the data parameter for a json ajax call.
 `data: "{str_" + sectionName + " :'" + UpdateText + "',EntityID: '" + EntityID + "' }",`
with update text being the string that can contain the quotes.

Comment: Providing a code sample would be very helpful

Comment: What are you doing with the input?

Comment: I'm sending it through ajax to a database.

here is the data parameter for a json ajax call.
data: "{str_" + sectionName + " :'" + UpdateText + "',EntityID: '" + EntityID + "' }",

with update text being the string that can contain the quotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could find one of the many String.replaceAll implementations or write your own, and just replace any single or double quotes with an escaped version like \" or \'.

Answer (score 23):

You need to escape the quotes with a \ or depending on how you plan to use the string you can use the javascript escape and unescape functions.

```
alert(escape("mike's"));
alert(unescape(escape("mike's")));
```

Also check this out for ways to [escape strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-strings-with-jquery)

Answer (score 5):

For escaping values in AJAX request, **Do not write your own implementation of escape or use [escape()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape) method.** *(`escape()` is deprecated)*. Instead create a JSON object and use `JSON.stringify` method.

For your case it should be like *(ignoring dynamic property for now)*:

```
//Create Javascript object    
var obj = { SectionName: UpdateText, EntityID: EntityID };
```

Later in your ajax request you can do :

```
data: JSON.stringify(obj),
```

If you want to use dynamic properties with your JSON object then for your particular case you can create the object in two steps like:

```
var obj = { EntityID: EntityID };
obj["str_" + sectionName] = UpdateText;
```

This practice will save you from manually escaping single/double quotes and other invalid characters. `JSON.stringify` will take care of that.

*(I came here looking for a somewhat similar issue, but couldn't find a suitable working solution, so ended up posting one here)*

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned AJAX, there is a possibility that the strings involving single quotes are getting rejected at the server side. 
Make sure you use `escape string function` provided , for example by php,  before inserting strings, to the database.

```
$user_name = $_REQUEST['username'];
$user_name = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$user_name);
$query = "INSERT into chat(username,message) VALUES('".$user_name."')";
```

This helps in escaping any single or double quotes that may appear in the '$user_name' string.
Also it prevents against any kind of SQL injection atacks!

Answer (score 0):

You should really sanitize your input inside your server-side script for a variety of reasons. If you're just displaying everything the user enters then your application can likely be used to launch a cross-site scripting attack.

Comment: I think his issue is that he's getting a javascript error, client-side, while trying to send data to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript has a built in method just for this that covers more than just single quotes.  Its called encodeURIComponent, from [Javascript Kit](http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/globalfunctions.shtml):

> Used to encode the parameter portion of a URI for characters that have special meaning, to separate them from reserved characters such as "&" that act as key/value separators. More inclusive than encodeURI(), it encodes all characters with special meaning in a URL string, including "=" and "&". Use this method only on the parameter portion of a URI; otherwise, the URI may no longer be valid if it contains one of the characters that are part of a valid URI (ie: "+") yet should be escaped if part of the URI parameter.

So your code should become:

```
data: "{str_" + encodeURIComponent(sectionName) + " :'" + encodeURIComponent(UpdateText) + "',EntityID: '" + encodeURIComponent(EntityID) + "' }",
```

I encode everything I send in a query string to be safe, but encoding the EntityID could arguably be skipped because it doesn't come from the user(I'm assuming), so you know it won't have special characters.

Comment: encodeURI and encodeURIComponent will not escape single quotes, at least not on current versions of Chrome/Safari

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to mbrevoort, 
I elaborate more on his answer

When You are sending a single quote in a query

```
empid = " T'via" 
empid = escape(empid)
```

When You get the value including a single quote

```
var xxx = request.QueryString("empid") 
xxx = unscape(xxx)
```

If you want to search/ insert the value which includes a single quote in a query

```
xxx = Replace(empid, "'", "''")
```

Answer (score 0):

To escape a single quote in Javascript use

```
UpdateText.replace('\'', '\\\'')
```

To escape all single quotes use

```
UpdateText.replace(/'/g, '\\\'')
```

Answer (score 0):

The **accepted answer** should not be the solution to use.

In order to send this through **AJAX** to **DB** where **request data** has **single quote** `'` in the string, do below:

1. Organize your **request data** as an **object**.

```
var data = {
  "sectionName" : sectionName, 
  "UpdateText" : updateText,
  "EntityID"  : entityID
}
```

2. **Stringfy** your **data** to **JSON** and send with **AJAX**

```
data = JSON.stringify(data); 
$.ajax({
            url: "",
            type: "POST",
            data: data, 
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json"
        }).done(function (res) {
            alert(res); 
        });
```

3. Depends on the **Database**, for **SQL Server**, replace your single quote `'` to double quote `''` to **escape the single quote** .

```
string data = date.Replace("'", "''")
```