# Sanitizing user input before adding it to the DOM in Javascript

Tags: javascript, escaping, xss, sanitization

I'm writing the JS for a chat application I'm working on in my free time, and I need to have HTML identifiers that change according to user submitted data. This is usually something conceptually shaky enough that I would not even attempt it, but I don't see myself having much of a choice this time. What I need to do then is to escape the HTML id to make sure it won't allow for XSS or breaking HTML.

Here's the code:

```
var user_id = escape(id)
var txt = '<div class="chut">'+
            '<div class="log" id="chut_'+user_id+'"></div>'+
            '<textarea id="chut_'+user_id+'_msg"></textarea>'+
            '<label for="chut_'+user_id+'_to">To:</label>'+
            '<input type="text" id="chut_'+user_id+'_to" value='+user_id+' readonly="readonly" />'+
            '<input type="submit" id="chut_'+user_id+'_send" value="Message"/>'+
          '</div>';
```

What would be the best way to escape `id` to avoid any kind of problem mentioned above? As you can see, right now I'm using the built-in `escape()` function, but I'm not sure of how good this is supposed to be compared to other alternatives. I'm mostly used to sanitizing input before it goes in a text node, not an id itself.

Comment: What exactly is the function of `id`?

Comment: the id right now is any string representing a user. I use it to differentiate similar structures of the page that belong to different users.

by that logic, MD5 or base64 could be a good wait to do it, I guess. There's just no built-in stuff for that.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

*Never* use `escape()`. It's nothing to do with HTML-encoding. It's more like URL-encoding, but it's not even properly that. It's a bizarre non-standard encoding available only in JavaScript.

If you want an HTML encoder, you'll have to write it yourself as JavaScript doesn't give you one. For example:

```
function encodeHTML(s) {
    return s.replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

However whilst this is enough to put your `user_id` in places like the `input value`, it's not enough for `id` because IDs can only use a limited selection of characters. (And `%` isn't among them, so `escape()` or even `encodeURIComponent()` is no good.)

You could invent your own encoding scheme to put any characters in an ID, for example:

```
function encodeID(s) {
    if (s==='') return '_';
    return s.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9.-]/g, function(match) {
        return '_'+match[0].charCodeAt(0).toString(16)+'_';
    });
}
```

But you've still got a problem if the same `user_id` occurs twice. And to be honest, the whole thing with throwing around HTML strings is usually a bad idea. Use DOM methods instead, and retain JavaScript references to each element, so you don't have to keep calling `getElementById`, or worrying about how arbitrary strings are inserted into IDs.

eg.:

```
function addChut(user_id) {
    var log= document.createElement('div');
    log.className= 'log';
    var textarea= document.createElement('textarea');
    var input= document.createElement('input');
    input.value= user_id;
    input.readonly= True;
    var button= document.createElement('input');
    button.type= 'button';
    button.value= 'Message';

    var chut= document.createElement('div');
    chut.className= 'chut';
    chut.appendChild(log);
    chut.appendChild(textarea);
    chut.appendChild(input);
    chut.appendChild(button);
    document.getElementById('chuts').appendChild(chut);

    button.onclick= function() {
        alert('Send '+textarea.value+' to '+user_id);
    };

    return chut;
}
```

You could also use a convenience function or JS framework to cut down on the lengthiness of the create-set-appends calls there.

ETA:

> I'm using jQuery at the moment as a framework

OK, then consider the jQuery 1.4 creation shortcuts, eg.:

```
var log= $('<div>', {className: 'log'});
var input= $('<input>', {readOnly: true, val: user_id});
...
```

> The problem I have right now is that I use JSONP to add elements and events to a page, and so I can not know whether the elements already exist or not before showing a message.

You can keep a lookup of `user_id` to element nodes (or wrapper objects) in JavaScript, to save putting that information in the DOM itself, where the characters that can go in an `id` are restricted.

```
var chut_lookup= {};
...

function getChut(user_id) {
    var key= '_map_'+user_id;
    if (key in chut_lookup)
        return chut_lookup[key];
    return chut_lookup[key]= addChut(user_id);
}
```

(The `_map_` prefix is because JavaScript objects don't *quite* work as a mapping of arbitrary strings. The empty string and, in IE, some `Object` member names, confuse it.)

Comment: I'm using jQuery at the moment as a framework, so any idea related to that can be helpful.

The problem I have right now is that I use JSONP to add elements and events to a page, and so I can not know whether the elements already exist or not before showing a message. This made me think I am forced to use the crappy method I have to find what elements to select or add them if they're not there already. Because of this, I don't think your last suggestion could work but I might be wrong.

The restricted character set makes me think an MD5 of the id could be all I can do.

Comment: Although I could just add an assumption about usernames' accepted characters, use regular expressions and be done with it.

Answer (score 77):

You can use this:

```
function sanitize(string) {
  const map = {
      '&': '&amp;',
      '<': '&lt;',
      '>': '&gt;',
      '"': '&quot;',
      "'": '&#x27;',
      "/": '&#x2F;',
  };
  const reg = /[&<>"'/]/ig;
  return string.replace(reg, (match)=>(map[match]));
}
```

Also see OWASP [XSS Prevention Cheat Sheet](https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross_Site_Scripting_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html).

Comment: what about backtick: ` ?

Comment: @JohnBalvinArias you can add it to the above exampe  its  `&grave;`

Comment: See this more complete solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: Sorry to bother but is there anyway this can be reversed? i don't know regex so i need help

Answer (score 14):

You could use a simple regular expression to assert that the id only contains allowed characters, like so:

```
if(id.match(/^[0-9a-zA-Z]{1,16}$/)){
    //The id is fine
}
else{
    //The id is illegal
}
```

My example allows only alphanumerical characters, and strings of length 1 to 16, you should change it to match the type of ids that you use.

By the way, at line 6, the value property is missing a pair of quotes, an easy mistake to make when you quote on two levels.

I can't see your actual data flow, depending on context this check may not at all be needed, or it may not be enough. In order to make a proper security review we would need more information.

In general, about built in escape or sanitize functions, don't trust them blindly. You need to know exactly what they do, and you need to establish that that is actually what you need. If it is not what you need, the code your own, most of the time a simple whitelisting regex like the one I gave you works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Since the text that you are escaping will appear in an HTML attribute, you must be sure to escape not only HTML entities but also HTML attributes:

```
var ESC_MAP = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#39;'
};

function escapeHTML(s, forAttribute) {
    return s.replace(forAttribute ? /[&<>'"]/g : /[&<>]/g, function(c) {
        return ESC_MAP[c];
    });
}
```

Then, your escaping code becomes `var user_id = escapeHTML(id, true)`.

For more information, see [Foolproof HTML escaping in Javascript](http://shebang.mintern.net/foolproof-html-escaping-in-javascript).

Answer (score 2):

You need to take extra precautions when using user supplied data in HTML attributes. Because  attributes has many more attack vectors than output inside HTML tags.

The only way to avoid XSS attacks is to encode everything except alphanumeric characters. Escape all characters with ASCII values less than 256 with the &#xHH; format. Which unfortunately may cause problems in your scenario, if you are using CSS classes and javascript to fetch those elements.

OWASP has a good description of how to mitigate HTML attribute XSS:

http://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet#RULE_.233_-_JavaScript_Escape_Before_Inserting_Untrusted_Data_into_HTML_JavaScript_Data_Values

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the comment of @SilentImp. if u need a typeScript version...

```typescript
export function sanitize(input: string) {
  const map: Record<string, string> = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#x27;',
    '/': '&#x2F;',
  };
  const reg = /[&<>"'/]/gi;

  return input.replace(reg, (match) => map[match]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The following approach to prevent XSS looks like a good solution.

```
var sanitizeHTML = function (str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\w. ]/gi, function (c) {
        return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });
};
```

Here is a working example:

```js
var sanitizeHTML = function (str) {
    return str.replace(/[^\w. ]/gi, function (c) {
        return '&#' + c.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    });
};

var app = document.querySelector('#app');
app.innerHTML = sanitizeHTML('<img src="x" onerror="alert(1)">');
```

```html
<div id="app">
        
</div>
```

This solution was [Provided Here](https://gomakethings.com/how-to-sanitize-third-party-content-with-vanilla-js-to-prevent-cross-site-scripting-xss-attacks/#sanitizing-by-encoding).