# Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, performance, string

I'm writing a Chrome extension that involves doing a **lot** of the following job: sanitizing strings that *might* contain HTML tags, by converting `<`, `>` and `&` to `&lt;`, `&gt;` and `&amp;`, respectively.

(In other words, the same as PHP's `htmlspecialchars(str, ENT_NOQUOTES)` – I don't think there's any real need to convert double-quote characters.)

This is the fastest function I have found so far:

```
function safe_tags(str) {
    return str.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;') ;
}
```

But there's still a big lag when I have to run a few thousand strings through it in one go.

Can anyone improve on this? It's mostly for strings between 10 and 150 characters, if that makes a difference.

(One idea I had was not to bother encoding the greater-than sign – would there be any real danger with that?)

Comment: Why? In most cases that you want to do this, you want to insert the data into the DOM, in which case you should forget about escaping it and just make a textNode from it.

Comment: @David Dorward: perhaps he wanted to sanitize POST data, and the server does not round-trip the data correctly.

Comment: @Lie — if so, then the solution is "For Pete's sake, fix the server as you have a big XSS hole"

Comment: @David Dorward: it is possible that the case is he do not have control over the server. I've been into such situation recently where I was writing a greasemonkey script to workaround a couple of things I don't like in my university's website; I had to do a POST on a server that I do not have control to and sanitize POST data using javascript (since the raw data comes from a rich textbox, and so has heaps of html tags which does not do round trip on the server). The web admin was ignoring my request for them to fix the website, so I had no other choice.

Comment: I have a use-case where I need to display an error message in a div. The error message can contain HTML and newlines. I want to escape the HTML and replace the newlines with <br>. Then put the result into a div for display.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You could try passing a callback function to perform the replacement:

```
var tagsToReplace = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;'
};

function replaceTag(tag) {
    return tagsToReplace[tag] || tag;
}

function safe_tags_replace(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>]/g, replaceTag);
}
```

Here is a performance test: http://jsperf.com/encode-html-entities to compare with calling the `replace` function repeatedly, and using the DOM method proposed by Dmitrij.

Your way seems to be faster...

Why do you need it, though?

Comment: There is no need to escape `>`.

Comment: Actually if you put the escaped value in an html element's attribute, you need to escape the > symbol. Otherwise it would break the tag for that html element.

Comment: In normal text escaped characters are rare. It's better to call replace only when needed, if you care about max speed: `if (/[<>&"]/.test(str) { ... }`

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit can you give an example where something could go wrong if you didn't escape `>`?

Comment: @callum: No. I am not interested in enumerating cases in which I think "something could go wrong" (not least because it's the unexpected/forgotten cases that'll hurt you, and when you least expect it at that). I am interested in coding to standards (so the unexpected/forgotten cases can't hurt you _by definition_). I can't stress how important this is. `>` is a special character in HTML, so escape it. Simple as that. :)

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I stick to standards as a default (for obvious maintenance reasons) but blindly following them to the letter 100% of the time is an opportunity cost. There are things that are nonstandard that are awesome. Not saying this one is a strong example. But dogma isn't always best in programming. You're interested in writing spec-compliant code, I'm interested in making real web browsers do real things. It's legitimate for me to ask you to back up your claim with something more than "because standards".

Comment: @callum: No, it's not, really. Your argument against following standards blindly is all well and good, and I support it, but you should follow standards _until you have a good reason not to_, not the other way around. Hence your question is vacuous. You should explain to me an example of where `>` must not be escaped, then explain how it's relevant to the OP here.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit It's relevant because the question is what is the fastest possible method. If it's possible to skip the `>` replacement, that would make it faster.

Comment: @callum: Now you're talking. :)

Comment: How to escape '"'?  
Am trying this '"':  '\"' , doesn't work

Comment: @nodeninja: a comment is not the place to ask a new question. You should ask that in a new question.

Comment: @Vitaly Too bad your comment is lost in all the noise.  You should have posted it as a solution.  The fact that the OP indicated the text "might contain HTML tags", implies that it often does not.  In such cases your test would have improved their speed significantly.

Answer (score 135):

Here's one way you can do this:

```
var escape = document.createElement('textarea');
function escapeHTML(html) {
    escape.textContent = html;
    return escape.innerHTML;
}

function unescapeHTML(html) {
    escape.innerHTML = html;
    return escape.textContent;
}
```

[Here's a demo.](http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/qPUEX)

Comment: Redesigned the demo. Here's a fullscreen version: http://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/qPUEX/show/light

Comment: Not sure how/what/why - but this is genius.

Comment: @Web_Designer can you explain this magic voodoo? Does it work in all browsers?

Comment: Looks like it is leveraging the TextArea element's existing code for escaping literal text.  Very nice, I think this little trick is going to find another home.

Comment: escape is now deprecated - see here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/escape
I used encodeURIComponent instead:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent

Comment: @jazkat I'm not using that function. The escape variable I use, I define myself in the example.

Comment: but does this lose white space etc.

Comment: It may not be useful if you have to show triangular braces as it will add an extra "&amp;"

Answer (score 32):

Martijn's method as a prototype function:

```
String.prototype.escape = function() {
    var tagsToReplace = {
        '&': '&amp;',
        '<': '&lt;',
        '>': '&gt;'
    };
    return this.replace(/[&<>]/g, function(tag) {
        return tagsToReplace[tag] || tag;
    });
};

var a = "<abc>";
var b = a.escape(); // "&lt;abc&gt;"
```

Comment: Add to `String` like this it should be **escapeHtml** since it's not an escaping for a String in general. That is `String.escapeHtml` is correct, but `String.escape` raises the question, "escape for what?"

Comment: Yeah good idea. I've moved away from extending the prototype these days to avoid conflicts.

Comment: If your browser has support for Symbol, you could use that instead to avoid polluting the string-key namespace.  var escape = new Symbol("escape"); String.prototype[escape] = function(){ ... };  "text"[escape]();

Comment: plus one for the example.

Answer (score 20):

An even quicker/shorter solution is:

```
escaped = new Option(html).innerHTML
```

This is related to some weird vestige of JavaScript whereby the Option element retains a constructor that does this sort of escaping automatically.

Credit to https://github.com/jasonmoo/t.js/blob/master/t.js

Comment: Neat one-liner but the [slowest method](https://jsperf.com/htmlentityencode/1) after regex. Also, the text here can have whitespace stripped, according to the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/2012/WD-html5-20121025/the-option-element.html#dom-option)

Comment: Note that @ShortFuse's "slowest method" link makes my system run out of RAM (with ~6GB free) and firefox seems to stop allocating just before it's out of memory so instead of killing the offending process, linux will sit there and let you do a hard power off.

Answer (score 15):

The fastest method is:

```
function escapeHTML(html) {
    return document.createElement('div').appendChild(document.createTextNode(html)).parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

This method is about twice faster than the methods based on 'replace', see http://jsperf.com/htmlencoderegex/35 .

Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17546215/698168

Comment: JSPerf shut-down in 2017, unfortunately - can you repost it to https://jsbench.me/ ?

Comment: @Dai : unfortunately I cant repost it as I'm not the benchmark author.

Answer (score 13):

The AngularJS source code also has a version inside of [angular-sanitize.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/67688d5ca00f6de4c7fe6084e2fa762a00d25610/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L450).

```
var SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP = /[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g,
    // Match everything outside of normal chars and " (quote character)
    NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP = /([^\#-~| |!])/g;
/**
 * Escapes all potentially dangerous characters, so that the
 * resulting string can be safely inserted into attribute or
 * element text.
 * @param value
 * @returns {string} escaped text
 */
function encodeEntities(value) {
  return value.
    replace(/&/g, '&amp;').
    replace(SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP, function(value) {
      var hi = value.charCodeAt(0);
      var low = value.charCodeAt(1);
      return '&#' + (((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000) + ';';
    }).
    replace(NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP, function(value) {
      return '&#' + value.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    }).
    replace(/</g, '&lt;').
    replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

Comment: Wow, that non-alphanum regex is intense.  I don't think the | in the expression is needed though.

Answer (score 10):

All-in-one script:

```
// HTML entities Encode/Decode

function htmlspecialchars(str) {
    var map = {
        "&": "&amp;",
        "<": "&lt;",
        ">": "&gt;",
        "\"": "&quot;",
        "'": "&#39;" // ' -> &apos; for XML only
    };
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
function htmlspecialchars_decode(str) {
    var map = {
        "&amp;": "&",
        "&lt;": "<",
        "&gt;": ">",
        "&quot;": "\"",
        "&#39;": "'"
    };
    return str.replace(/(&amp;|&lt;|&gt;|&quot;|&#39;)/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
function htmlentities(str) {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.innerHTML = str;
    return textarea.innerHTML;
}
function htmlentities_decode(str) {
    var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
    textarea.innerHTML = str;
    return textarea.value;
}
```

http://pastebin.com/JGCVs0Ts

Comment: I didn't downvote, but all regex style replace will fail to encode unicode... So, anyone using a foreign language is going to be disappointed.  The <textarea> trick mentioned above is really cool and handles everything quickly and securely.

Comment: The regex works fine for me with a number of non-Latin Unicode characters. I wouldn't expect anything else. How do you think this wouldn't work? Are you thinking of single-byte codepages that require HTML entities? That's what the 3rd and 4th function are for, and explicitly not the 1st and second. I like the differentiation.

Comment: @LonelyPixel I don't think he will see your comment if you don't mention him ("Only one additional user can be notified; the post owner will always be notified")

Comment: I didn't know targeted notifications exist at all. @Ajax please see my comment above.

Comment: @LonelyPixel I see now.  For some reason I didn't think there was a textarea style replacement in this answer.  I was, indeed, thinking of double codepoint big unicode values, like Mandarin.  I mean, it would be possible to make a regex smart enough, but when you look at the shortcuts that browser vendors can take, I would feel pretty good betting that textarea will be much faster (than a completely competent regex).  Did someone post a benchmark on this answer?  I swore I had seen one.

Answer (score 4):

```js
function encode(r) {
  return r.replace(/[\x26\x0A\x3c\x3e\x22\x27]/g, function(r) {
 return "&#" + r.charCodeAt(0) + ";";
  });
}

test.value=encode('How to encode\nonly html tags &<>\'" nice & fast!');

/*
 \x26 is &ampersand (it has to be first),
 \x0A is newline,
 \x22 is ",
 \x27 is ',
 \x3c is <,
 \x3e is >
*/
```

```html
<textarea id=test rows=11 cols=55>www.WHAK.com</textarea>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'll add `XMLSerializer` to the pile. It provides the fastest result without using any object caching (not on the serializer, nor on the Text node).

```
function serializeTextNode(text) {
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.createTextNode(text));
}
```

The added bonus is that it supports attributes which is serialized differently than text nodes:

```
function serializeAttributeValue(value) {
  const attr = document.createAttribute('a');
  attr.value = value;
  return new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(attr);
}
```

You can see what it's actually replacing by checking the spec, both for [text nodes](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#xml-serializing-a-text-node) and for [attribute values](https://w3c.github.io/DOM-Parsing/#dfn-serializing-an-attribute-value). The full documentation has more node types, but the concept is the same.

As for performance, it's the fastest when not cached. When you do allow caching, then calling `innerHTML` on an HTMLElement with a child Text node is fastest. Regex would be slowest (as proven by other comments). Of course, XMLSerializer could be faster on other browsers, but in my (limited) testing, a `innerHTML` is fastest.

---

Fastest single line:

`new XMLSerializer().serializeToString(document.createTextNode(text));`

Fastest with caching:

```
const cachedElementParent = document.createElement('div');
const cachedChildTextNode = document.createTextNode('');
cachedElementParent.appendChild(cachedChildTextNode);

function serializeTextNode(text) {
  cachedChildTextNode.nodeValue = text;
  return cachedElementParent.innerHTML;
}
```

https://jsperf.com/htmlentityencode/1

Answer (score 1):

Martijn's method as single function with handling **"** mark (*using in javascript*) :

```
function escapeHTML(html) {
    var fn=function(tag) {
        var charsToReplace = {
            '&': '&amp;',
            '<': '&lt;',
            '>': '&gt;',
            '"': '&#34;'
        };
        return charsToReplace[tag] || tag;
    }
    return html.replace(/[&<>"]/g, fn);
}
```

Comment: this solution I have also found in Vue framework https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/b51430f598b354ed60851bb62885539bd25de3d8/src/platforms/web/server/util.js#L50

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure about speed, but if you are looking for simplicity I would suggest using the lodash/underscore [escape](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#escape) function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment by @Vitaly, and the fact the OP indicated the text "might contain HTML tags", the following helps significantly with text that rarely needs to be escaped.

```
  static escapeHtml(str) {
    return !(/[<>&"']/.test(str)) ? str :
           str.replaceAll('&', '&amp;')   .replaceAll('<', '&lt;')
              .replaceAll('>', '&gt;')    .replaceAll('"', '&quot;');
  }
```

Answer (score -5):

A bit late to the show, but what's wrong with using [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent)?

Comment: Those do something completely unrelated

Comment: Perhaps the biggest abuse of the word "completely" I have ever heard. For example, in relation to the main topic question, it could be used to decode a html string (obviously for some kinda storage reason), regardless of html tags, and then easily encode it back to html again when and if required.

Comment: @callum is correct: the question asks about html entities, and you answer about uri components, which _are_ completely different.