# recognize html code

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a javascript function that recognize if a string variable contains HTML code? 
I would like to avoid this case because if I use innerHTML and the user has submitted something like `<img src='link'>` it doesn't appear the string but the real image...
I hope I explained
Thank you!

Comment: Have a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities

Comment: Simple solution: Don't use innerHTML. `document.createTextNode('some string')`

Comment: and this works with the tag <br> ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just replace 3 very special characters:
`&`: used for glyph notation
`<`: opening bracket for html tags
`>`: closeing bracket for html tags

```
function make_safe(input) {
    return input.replace("&", "&amp;").replace(/(<?)([^<>]*)(>?)/g, function (a,b,c,d) {
        if ((b+c+d).toLowerCase() === "<br>") return "<br>";

        if (b === "<") b = "&lt;";
        if (b === ">") b = "&gt;";

        if (d === "<") d = "&lt;";
        if (d === ">") d = "&gt;";

        return b+c+d;
    }).replace(/\r?\n/g,"<br>");
}

// example:
mydiv.innerHTML = make_safe('<img src="/pic.jpg">');
```

I did a little magic so \r\n becomes a newline, and `<br>` tags are preserved

Comment: tha fact is that in the string I must have the tag <br>

Comment: Is that the only character you need?

Comment: if the userinput uses carriage return/newline feeds instead of `<br>`, use the above.

Comment: Updated my answer so `<br>` tags are preserved.

Comment: thank you! later I will try and I can give you the correct answer

Answer (score 1):

Not really. Telling the difference between HTML and text talking about HTML is not a trivial problem.

If you are expecting text input, then deal with text not HTML. Don't use `innerHTML`, use `createTextNode` and `appendChild`/`insertBefore`.

Comment: `createTextNode` gives no special meaning to the `<` or `>` characters at all. It takes a string and treats it as plain text to be added to the DOM, not HTML that needs to be parsed.

Comment: tha fact is that in the string I must have the tag <br>

Comment: @Marty – So you want *some* HTML to be escaped and *some* HTML to be passed through? That is a different and much, much more complicated problem.