# can't pass html tags in parameters in $.post()

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using a userControl in MVC 4 that has a telerik radeditor. 
I want to submit the content of the radeditor the the action method but if I user editor.get_html() the code doesn't execute.

the javascript call to the action method is the following:

```
function Save() {
    var editor = $find("<%=radEdit.ClientID%>");          
    var editorHtmlContent = editor.get_html(); 
    var entityId = document.getElementById('hdEntityId').value;           
    var url = '<%=Url.Action("SaveNote", "staticController")%>';
    $.post(url, { EntityId: entityId, Desc: editorHtmlContent }, function (result) { });
}
```

any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Posting HTML tags is being considered a security threat (HTML Injection and Cross-site Scripting (XSS)), so it is blocked by default. You have three ways out of this:

1. Encode your HTML on client side before sending to the server. You can find a lot of reading about that on SO, for example here: [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities)
2. If you have strongly typed model class and want to get the actual HTML, you can use `AllowHtmlAttribute`:

   ```
   public class XMLModel
   {
       public int EntityId { get; set; }

       [AllowHtml]
       public string Desc { get; set; }
   }
   ```
3. Last option is to disable input validation for entire action, which can be done with `ValidateInputAttribute`:

   ```
   [ValidateInput(false)]
   [HttpPost]
   public ActionResult SaveNote(...)
   {
       ...
   }
   ```

You should choose the option most suitable for you.