# Regex undesireably removing substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to extract `void <init>(java.lang.String)` and `java.io.File getOutputMediaFileUri(int)` from the string below (and strings like it).

```
specialinvoke $r1.<java.io.File: void <init>(java.lang.String)>($r16)@<com.jpgextractor.PicViewerActivity: java.io.File getOutputMediaFileUri(int)>
```

Currently, I'm matching to the regex:

```
/.*<.* (\S+ .*)>.*<.* (\S+ .*)>.*/
```

Which works, except for instead of `void <init>(java.lang.String)` I just get `void (java.lang.String)`.

I'm a bit mistified where `<init>` has gone off too...I've tried several different ways to coax it back, but so far no luck.

Thanks folks!

Comment: What is the tool you are using to extract the text?

Comment: javascript regex built-ins

Comment: You are getting the result: http://rubular.com/r/uWqCnA7c8N

Comment: Ah, so it's not displaying in a web page? Needs to be escaped?

Comment: @bcr: The problem is how you are displaying the text. Can you show the code?

Comment: Here's the result from a javascript regex tool: http://goo.gl/W71sBX .  If you are printing the result in a page, the browser is probably interpreting `<init>` as a tag (**and thus showing nothing, as that tag has no meaning in HTML**). Try outputting the result with `console.log(RESULT)`.

Comment: Yes, so I need to escape the tags. That does make sense.

Comment: should I delete this question then or update to reflect the real problem? I'm aware of how to escape the resulting string, but perhaps this could be a useful reference for noobs like me

Comment: @bcr: Just answer yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was nothing to do with the regex; as pointed out by acdcjunior and nhahtdh, the regex was operating correctly, but the issue was in displaying the text. I was putting the output `void <init>()` into a web page as unescaped HTML, where `<init>` was interpreted as an HTML tag; the `<>` characters should be escaped.

See [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) for information on escaping such tags.