# Jquery escape only a part of the string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, escaping

I am stuck on trying to escape only part of a string in jquery.

So straight to the example

```
$("#tbody").append("Hi <escape this> and <not this>");
```

I know that I can escape it by doing this.

```
$("#tbody").text("Hi <escape this> and <not this>");
```

but then the whole string gets escaped and its not just a row but the whole context of the tbody.

then I tried to put it in several appends like this

```
$("#tbody").append("Hi");
$("#void").text("<escape this>").appendTo("#tbody");
$("#tbody").append("and <not this>");
```

Now this creates rows for each append and breaks the structure of my entry as it should only by one row.

Kind Regards

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this...

```
var textToBody = "Hi " + escape("<escape this>") + " and <not this>";
$("#tbody").append(textToBody);
```

[More Help...](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_escape.asp)

Comment: Yes but escape() outputs it as %3Cescape%20this%3E which is not what I want, I still want it displayed in its normal form.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [HTML Entities](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_entities.asp) as jQuery's `append()` would not parse them and the browser should display them as text:

```
$("#tbody").append("Hi &lt;escape this&gt; and <not this>");
```

Output should be:

> Hi <escape this> and

The `<not this>` is rendered as a HTML tag, thus it will not be shown as text.

Comment: Yes fair enough, my mistake that I did not complete my Question. The <escape this> would be data from a user. Thanks

Comment: @user2715411 then you can do that with simple replaces (first thing that comes in mind!): `var userData = "Fetch <data> any <way>"; userData = userData.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;');`.

Comment: Cool I will do this but isnt there a better way? I feel this is not the best way as the input can be anything so i will have to check for each special character that exist.

Comment: You can do a little research yourself for that, but in most cases [the above replace example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) is used or [jQuery's `.text()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) as you tried.