# how to display a script tag in html and not execute it

Tags: javascript

I want to display a script tag that looks like: `<script..`

if I run JavaScript

```
encodeURI("<script")
```

Then output that to the browser it no longer looks like `< script`

I'm strong it on my backend with the real less than sign but want to convert it with javascript, then display that conversion as html I assume with <

Is there a javascript function that will do this? (obviously not encodeURI)

thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must use a method or a tool which escapes some html characters.

For a tool please see http://www.iwantaneff.in/entifier/ for sample

So your code will be

```
&lt;script&gt;
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no native function, but you can manually create one:

```
function htmlEscape(str) {
    return str.replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;');
}
```

You can manually do replace like that.

Call it like this:

```
htmlEscape('<script');
```