# Display <script> tag inside the div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to display user input inside the div. But if the user put in  tag, it will execute whatever inside the script tag.

For example

```
<html>
<body>
    <button onclick="runTest('<script>alert(\'test\')</script>')">Click Me</button>
    <div id="test"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

And my javascript runTest function

```
function runTest(str) {
    $('#test').append($('<div>' + str + '</div>'));
}
```

If I run this, it will cause alert() to be executed. I tried to use escape(str), but it displays the escape characters `%3Cscript%3Ealert%28%27test%27%29%3C/script%3E`

Any idea? Here is the fiddler: https://jsfiddle.net/zvLg1w6q/1/

Thanks...

Comment: It seems like your question already has a answer at the link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22876625/how-to-display-a-script-tag-in-html-and-not-execute-it . Use htmlEscape function from that link.

Comment: @Fraddy, you are a life saver. I search everywhere on google but couldn't find this simple solution. Please post your solution and I'll accept it.

Comment: you can upvote my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use this function:

```
function htmlencode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function($0) {
        return "&" + {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"}[$0] + ";";
    });
}
```

and use it same as follow:

```js
function htmlencode(str) {
    return str.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function($0) {
        return "&" + {"&":"amp", "<":"lt", ">":"gt", '"':"quot", "'":"#39"}[$0] + ";";
    });
}

document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML = htmlencode('<scrip t>alert("hi")</scrip t>')
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">

</div>
```