# Partial HTML string escaping in Angular.js

Tags: javascript, angularjs, security, angular-translate

I have read about angular's way of escaping **everything by default** and [`$sce`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$sce), so I white-list data with `$sce.trustAsHtml()` through filter (since `$sce` is not working in service), like this:

```
<sup class="ng-binding" ng-bind-html="row|logEntry"></sup>
```

But the problem is, that I don't trust some parts of HTML.

To dive into details - I have [translations](https://github.com/angular-translate/angular-translate) that have HTML in it, but they have replaceable tokens/variables in them. So [translations support HTML](http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/06_variable-replacement), but I don't want provided tokens to include HTML.

My filter `logEntry` internally looks like this:

```
var translated = $translate('Log.' + msg.context.entity_type) + '.' + msg.context.action, {
        'object_name': msg.context.object_name,
        'user': msg.context.user_name
});
return $sce.trustAsHtml(translated);
```

*For example I can have translation about userX changing article, but I don't want result text to trigger alert() if user's name includes `<script>alert('evilname')</script>`*

`$translate` by itself is not relevant, it can be any HTML string where I want some parts to be replaced with regular JS `.replace()` with content staying "as text".

So my question is - **how can I escape parts of HTML**? Do I have to resort to slicing it in parts inside of a view? Or do I have to resort to custom escaping (
[Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) )? Is there a preferred practice for such things?

Answer (score 5):

Let's start by restructuring your `logEntry` to separate out the interpolateParams

```
var translationId = 'Log.' + msg.context.entity_type) + '.' + msg.context.action;
var interpolateParams = {
        'object_name': msg.context.object_name,
        'user': msg.context.user_name
};
var translated = $translate(translationId, interpolateParams);
return $sce.trustAsHtml(translated);
```

You want to escape all HTML from `interpolateParams` but leave any HTML in your translation templates.  Use this code to copy the object, iterate over its values and replace with escaped HTML.

```
var safeParams = angular.copy(interpolateParams);    
angular.forEach(safeParams, function(value, key, obj) {     
  obj[key] = encodeEntities(value)
  // if you want safe/sanitized HTML, use this instead
  // obj[key] = $sanitize(value);
});
var translated = $translate(translationId, safeParams);
```

Lastly, the `encodeEntities` functionality of angular isn't exposed, so we had to borrow the source from [angular-sanitize.js](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/67688d5ca00f6de4c7fe6084e2fa762a00d25610/src/ngSanitize/sanitize.js#L450)

```
var SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP = /[\uD800-\uDBFF][\uDC00-\uDFFF]/g,
    // Match everything outside of normal chars and " (quote character)
    NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP = /([^\#-~| |!])/g;
function encodeEntities(value) {
  return value.
    replace(/&/g, '&amp;').
    replace(SURROGATE_PAIR_REGEXP, function(value) {
      var hi = value.charCodeAt(0);
      var low = value.charCodeAt(1);
      return '&#' + (((hi - 0xD800) * 0x400) + (low - 0xDC00) + 0x10000) + ';';
    }).
    replace(NON_ALPHANUMERIC_REGEXP, function(value) {
      return '&#' + value.charCodeAt(0) + ';';
    }).
    replace(/</g, '&lt;').
    replace(/>/g, '&gt;');
}
```

**Update:** After updating to angular-translate 2.7.0 this message appeared:

> pascalprecht.translate.$translateSanitization: No sanitization
>   strategy has been configured. This can have serious security
>   implications. See
>   http://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/19_security for
>   details.

Sp instead of the `trustlate` answer above, angular-translate can accomplish the same result with:

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
```

See the docs for more *Sanitize Value Strategies*

Answer (score 3):

In your app add

```
$translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');
```

So that, your code looks like this :

```
myApp.config(function ($translateProvider) {

    //...whatever

  $translateProvider.useSanitizeValueStrategy('escapeParameters');

});
```