# jQuery command other than appendTo

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to clear an LI tag's previous data.

Is there another command that will work other than appendTo?

Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(data);
 $.each(obj, function(index, item)
 {
   $('<li>').
     text(item.datestamp+' - '+item.comment).
     appendTo($('#pCodeComment'));
 });
```

I asked a similar question not too long ago.  I just want to know if there is another command other than appendTo that will clear out the previous data.

Comment: In this case you're likely better off using .empty to empty the target. However, that makes no sense, because you're doing this in a loop... I guess, unless you empty it before the loop.

Comment: @KevinB - good eyes, the loop sorta messes it up if you remove the content on each iteration.

Comment: In other words, just do `$('#pCodeComment').empty()` before `$.each`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should empty the list before you loop to populate it, then just continue doing what you are already doing.

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data);
$('#pCodeComment').empty();
$.each(obj, function(index, item)
{
  $('<li>').
    text(item.datestamp+' - '+item.comment).
    appendTo($('#pCodeComment'));
});
```

And after optimizing a little bit:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(data); // i'm assuming `obj` is an array
var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item) {
        return '<li>' + item.datestamp + ' - ' + item.comment + '</li>';
    }).join('');
$('#pCodeComment').html(htmlToInsert);
```

<sub>**Note: the above is vulnerable to XSS. See [this so question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) for ways to fix it, or just use the original.**</sub>

Comment: You might want to consider not making that selection N+1 times.

Comment: Definitely a good idea, just didn't want to change code that wasn't relevant to the answer. I would take it a step further and generate a plain text html string and insert/empty all in one step with .html.

Comment: This new version has an XSS vulnerability the older one did not have. If item.comment contains <script>alert("HI")</script> for instance.

Comment: @Kevin B - Any chance you can help me fix the code to check to see if the JSON data is blank, and if so, keep the LI tag clear of anything?

Comment: @HoodCoderMan please do not ask several questions in one thread it is considered rude in Stack Overflow to do that. You can open a new question if you'd like.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum - I will take that into consideration. Only reason I asked is because I cannot post another question for 90 minutes now. That is all.

Comment: Could fix the xss issue using a method similar to one of the methods here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities

Answer (score 0):

```
$.replaceWith()
```

might be what you are looking for, or as Kevin B pointed out

```
$.html()
```

replaceWith would need an element selected to replace. whilst html will populate a parent element to insert a new dom fragment into.