# How to block angularJS from parsing/running a directive or code block?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

My problem sounds easy but I haven't found a solution yet and I've searched for it a lot at google and here at SO.

I'd like to create a demo html page for my custom directive and in it I'd like to show the markup of the directive in a code block (similar to how it is in the [angular docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/input)). But I don't need it to be dynamic (no syntax highlighting, no tabs).

For me it would be OK to have the code just as plain text but Angular parses the directive and executes the code.

How can I block angular to execute the directive?

It should look like this:

```
Text that describes the directive ..............

    <directive1 parameter1="test"></directive1>

Then the rendered directive result here
```

What I've tried so far?

- move the ng-app below the description: Doesn't work (directive markup will be hidden)
- nesting in different html tags `span, pre, code` but none is working.
- placing the angular directive in an `iframe`. Not working, always empty in jsFiddle.

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jL64wdtk/) I've setup a simple jsFiddle demo. (My directive is a bit more complicated but it shows the problem.)

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('simpleDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: 'I\'m a simple directive!'
    };
});
```

```css
pre {
    background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<h2>Usage of directive</h2>
<p>Here I'd like to describe my directive and show the directive in a code block
    (but how do I block angular to execute the directive?!)</p>
<pre><code>
    <simple-directive></simple-directive>
    </code>
</pre>
^--- the above directive must not run. 
<!--<div ng-app="myApp"> doesn't work-->
<p>The following directive code shows the result:</p>
<simple-directive></simple-directive>
<!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: You can use ngnonbindable attribute on the element which you don't want to run the angularjs directive

Comment: Yes, the directive is not running but the markup isn't showing in the page. The markup will be hidden with `ng-non-bindable`attribute. So no option for me, but thanks for the tipp. It's useful to disable a directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One simple solution is set the element `text` with the html for directive:

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
.directive('code', function(){
    return{
        restrict:'E',
        link:function(scope, elem){
            elem.text('<simple-directive></simple-directive>')
        }
    }
});
```

Of course you could simplify this to feed the html from your data model and thereby have numerous blocks like this with scope defined by attributes or pull it from one of your templates in a script tag

Angular won't compile when you insert html outside of angular and don't use `$compile`

Another simple solution is put it in a script tag and set `display:block` on that tag.

HTML

```
<script id="script-block" type="text/demo">
    <simple-directive></simple-directive>
</script>
```

CSS

```
#script-block{    
    display:block;
    background: yellow
}
```

Script tag approach could also be made into a directive

Personally I would use a syntax highlighter to do all this for you. Lots of choices for those around

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jL64wdtk/8/)**</kbd>

Comment: Great answer. You could also add the text for the code block directive as parameter. See this fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jL64wdtk/9/). OK, I'll google for a syntax highlighter.

Comment: right...I was updating my answer with the same thing. Syntax highlighter directive is still the best and they are easy to use

Comment: Yes, that's it. I think angular-highlighjs is a way to go. There are probably many others but this one is very easy to use. Please have a look at this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/jL64wdtk/10/).

Answer (score 2):

You could always html encode the `<` and `>`:

So the `<code>` block looks like:

```
<code>&lt;simple-directive&gt;&lt;/simple-directive&gt;</code>
```

You could do this in JavaScript by doing [something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities).

**Edited Snippet:**

```js
angular.module('myApp', [])

.directive('simpleDirective', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        template: 'I\'m a simple directive!'
    };
});
```

```css
pre {
    background: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp">
<h2>Usage of directive</h2>
<p>Here I'd like to describe my directive and show the directive in a code block
    (but how do I block angular to execute the directive?!)</p>
<pre><code>
    &lt;simple-directive&gt;&lt;/simple-directive&gt;
    </code>
</pre>
^--- the above directive must not run. 
<!--<div ng-app="myApp"> doesn't work-->
<p>The following directive code shows the result:</p>
<simple-directive></simple-directive>
<!-- </div> -->
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, that's right and simple as I've expected. But I think the other answer is also great because it avoids escaping and it's easier to write for more code examples.

Comment: Yes @charlietfl's solution looks pretty sweet!