# How to grab only the text of HTML elements in a safe and secure way

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xss

So `"<h1>Hello World</h1>"` will just return 'Hello World'.

I've tried:

```
$('<div>').html('<h1>Hello World</h1>').text()
```

And that works fine in most cases, but it does open up an xss vulnerability for when the string is something like this: `<img src=1 onerror=alert(/XSS/)>`, when I expect it to return an empty string

Comment: "but it doesn't open up an xss vulnerability" Do you mean "*does* open up"?

Comment: well, that depends on where this string is coming from...

Comment: Yes I mean it "does" open up an xss vulnerability

Comment: `var d=document.createElement("template");d.innerHTML='0<img src=1 onerror=alert(/XSS/)>1'; alert(d.content.textContent);`

Comment: @dandavis, fantastic!  using a template element will work.  I'm not sure you added the numbers there, but they are not needed.  Thanks!

Comment: @JasonM: the numbers show that text makes it through; an empty string alone could be coincidence...

Comment: @dandavis, this doesn't seem to working browsers that don't support the template tag.  Any suggestions on this? Thanks!

Comment: @JasonM: `alert(new DOMParser().parseFromString('0<img src=1 onerror=alert(/XSS/) >1'.bold(),"text/html").documentElement.textContent);`  (whew, i was about to say no, then i recalled that dom parser started doing non-strict html...) picks up IE10+

Comment: @dandavis, your wealth of knowledge impresses me :) any chance for a solution in ie 9?

Answer (score 2):

You can try this code found here- [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities)

```
function sanitize(str) {
  return str.replace(/&/g,'').replace(/</g,'').replace(/>/g,'');
}
```

In your example, assuming there's html that looks like this:

```
<div><img src=1 onerror=alert(/XSS/)></div>
```

simply sanitize it like so:

```
var string = $('div').text();
var sanitized = sanitize(string); // "img src=1 onerror=alert(/XSS/);"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  In the case of: <div><img src=1 onerror=alert(/XSS/)></div>, I'd expect it to return an empty string because there isn't any text involved.