# How to display html string using Em.String.htmlSafe?

Tags: ember.js, htmlbars

My requirement is list all customers one by one in newline.

```
let customers = [ {id: 1, name: "a"}, {id: 2, name: "b"}]

let displayString = customers.mapBy("name").join("</br>");

displayString = Ember.String.htmlSafe(displayString);
```

Now I am doing like this. The problem is if the customer name has any html tags in the name, that is also rendering. How to avoid this?

Comment: Cant you use `#each` to display the names??

Comment: Solution 1) use #each in the template as mentionned AcidBurn. Solution 2) [escape html tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities) (note the method in the question is faster than all answers).