# Double escaping angle bracelet and ampersand

Tags: javascript

I applied [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499821/492258) in project, I need to escape both at client and server:

```js
function replaceTag(tag) {
        var tagsToReplace = {
            "&": "&amp;",
            "<": "&lt;",
            ">": "&gt;"
        };
        return tagsToReplace[tag] || tag;
    }

    function safe_tags_replace(str) {
        var self = this;
        return str.replace(/[&<>]/g, self.replaceTag);
    }
    
    var result = safe_tags_replace(">");
    result = safe_tags_replace(result);
    console.log(result);
```

How can I make special character `>` is "escaped" to  `&gt;` instead of `&amp;gt;`

Comment: Why do you think you need to call `safe_tags_replace` twice? That's why you have double escaping...?

Comment: First of all, why do you think you need this on both the client and the server? Typically you'd handle this on the server only.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts it is chat application, and sender also should display message at his screen, but if it is hacked then I should also escape at server

Comment: Then what would be the purpose of doing it server side if it's just for rendering ?

Comment: For displaying messages on a client, assign to `element.textContent` or use `document.createTextNode()`, there's no need to do this.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/[<>]|&(?!amp;|gt;|lt;)/g
```

using it like this:

```
str.replace(/[<>]|&(?!amp;|gt;|lt;)/g, self.replaceTag);
```

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak Use this regex in `str.replace`, I've updated the code. It will replace `&` only if not followed by `amp;` `gt;` or `lt;`.

Answer (score 0):

There's no need to reinvent the wheel here. If you just need to display text without rendering HTML, use a built-in escape mechanism like this:

```js
var
  input = document.getElementById('input'),
  chat = document.getElementById('chat');

input.addEventListener('keypress', function(event) {
  if ((event.keyCode || event.which) === 13) {
    var msg = document.createElement('div');

    msg.textContent = input.value;
    // msg.appendChild(document.createTextNode(input.value));

    input.value = '';

    chat.appendChild(msg);
  }
});
```

```html
<div id="chat"></div>
<input id="input" type="text" value="&lt;script&gt;alert('dangerous');&lt;/script&gt;"/>
```

Press `Enter` and see what happens. *I dare you.*