# Escaping < and > in JavaScript code when assigning it to InnerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, html-agility-pack

I am adding some javascript code to a script tag programmatically by assigning it to InnerHtml property of the HtmlNode

```
scriptNode.InnerHtml =new_script;
```

and my javascript contains less than `<` and/or greater than `>` characters and that causes problems - distorts my resulting javascript. How can I escape those.

Here is a sample javascript that is causing the problem:

```
function myFunc(el){
    var i=0
    for (;i < el.choice.length;i++){
        ....
    }
}
```

How can I escape the `<` in the code above while assigning the code as InnerHtml for my Html node?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078/fastest-method-to-escape-html-tags-as-html-entities)

Comment: No, that does nto work for me. I am dealing with actual javascript code that gets edited when assigned to innerHtml

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can either use HTML codes of `>` and `<` which are `&lt;` and `&gt;`

OR

You can wrap your script within `CDATA` like this:

```
<script>
    <![CDATA[
        --YOUR SCRIPT--
    ]]>
</script>
```

Comment: It would be nice if an explanation is given for the downvote. If it's a valid reason, I will even delete the answer to prevent further confusion. Cheers

Comment: let me try, I think it might work for me. Keeping my fingers crossed

Comment: it worked! I still hsve to figure out if there are downsides to using CDATA but other than that it worked! Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help Elena :) Cheers

Comment: CDATA would break if the script contained `]]>`.

Answer (score 2):

For that you need to encode and decode the javascript content. please refer the following code :

```
function htmlEncode(value){
  //create a in-memory div, set it's inner text(which jQuery automatically encodes)
  //then grab the encoded contents back out.  The div never exists on the page.
  return $('<div/>').text(value).html();
}

function htmlDecode(value){
  return $('<div/>').html(value).text();
}

htmlEncode('<b>test</b>')
// result"&lt;b&gt;test&lt;/b&gt;"
```

As posted [previously](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1219860/javascript-jquery-html-encoding) by @CMS

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple code that escapes a string:

```
function escapeHtml(text) {
  var map = {
    '&': '&amp;',
    '<': '&lt;',
    '>': '&gt;',
    '"': '&quot;',
    "'": '&#039;'
  };

  return text.replace(/[&<>"']/g, function(m) { return map[m]; });
}
```

Comment: These aren't the only special characters though