# Escape Chars in Email Templates

Tags: gmail, escaping, email-templates

I have an email template that contains a var - `${token}` for a temporary password. In this case, token == `@.iJ<ep2C]a-d$}4xK{`. When rendered in Gmail token is truncated at the < character and rendered as `@.iJ`. How can I escape chars in token so they render correctly in Gmail?

***Template***

```
From: info@mycompany.com
Subject: New User Activation
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="alternative_boundary"

This is a message with multiple parts in MIME format.

--alternative_boundary
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit

Dear ${firstName} ${lastName},

Please click on the below link and use Temporary password: ${token} to activate your new account.

${reset_url}


--alternative_boundary
Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<title>New account activation</title>

</head>
<body>
    <p>Dear ${firstName} ${lastName},</p>
    <p>Please click <a href="${reset_url}">here</a> to activate your new account and use verification code: ${token} in the page</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What language is that? It looks like JavaScript string interpolation in a template literal using `${value}`.

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to escape [the reserved characters](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Entity#Reserved_characters) per the MDN docs:

- `&`   `&amp;`
- `<`   `&lt;`
- `>`   `&gt;`
- `"`   `&quot;`

Gmail thinks the `<` is the start of an HTML tag.

Assuming you're using JavaScript replace these in the token like [Fastest method to escape HTML tags as HTML entities?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5499078):

```
function escapeHtmlEntities(str) {
  return str
    .replace(/&/g, '&amp;')
    .replace(/</g, '&lt;')
    .replace(/>/g, '&gt;')
    .replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

In your template:

```
...${escapeHtmlEntities(token)}...
```

Comment: Correct, is there a way to do that in the template i.e., adding some sort of filter to ${token} in the template?

Comment: Maybe. You didn't mention what templates you're using.

Comment: Thanks, I added the email template.