# How to escape html and urls in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, character-encoding, escaping

Say I have the following Javascript:

```
var userString = "..."; // e.g. "cats < dogs"
```

How do I get `userString` with all html characters escaped?

E.g. I want `cats &lt; dogs`.

Also, how do I do the same thing with escaping all URL characters?

E.g. I want `cats%20%3C%20dogs`

I realize I could use a function [such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5499821/35690), but it seems to be non-exhaustive. E.g. it's missing `&quot;`.

Since Javascript does not seem to have a built-in method, I'm hoping that Google Apps Script has a built-in solution.

Answer (score 1):

From what I can tell, you need to use a [function such as this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12034334/35690) for HTML encoding, and [encodeURI()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURI) for URLs.