# Applying different styles in substrings of strings containing html tags

Tags: html, css

I wanted to capture the user's text-input in a variable USER_INPUT and use the value of that variable as a substring of a multi-styled string that is shown in some DISPLAY div. But there were problems with text-inputs containing html tags, like `<div>`, as in the following example, where the value of USER_INPUT does not appear at all in DISPLAY, which is understandable, due to the different nature of the .innerText and .innerHTML properties.

```
var USER_INPUT = "<div>";
      
document.getElementById("DISPLAY").innerHTML =  
       "<span style='color:red'>" + "User Input : " + "</span>" + 
       "<span style='color:blue'>" + USER_INPUT + "</span>";
```

So after much experimentation, a solution appeared which seems to work well in all cases:

```
var USER_INPUT = "<div>";
    
var XDIV = document.createElement("div");
XDIV.innerText = USER_INPUT;
var A = XDIV.innerHTML;
    
document.getElementById("DISPLAY").innerHTML =  
       "<span style='color:red'>" + "User Input : " + "</span>" + 
       "<span style='color:blue'>" + A + "</span>";
```

The above code shows in the DISPLAY:  [image]
which is exactly what I need, that is, to be able to style the user-input independently of the first part of the string.

My problem is that I cannot understand why the above code solves the problem. If the user-input string is passed in a new div as innerText and retrieved as innerHTML, then it miraculously appears correctly in the DISPLAY. I would like to understand the rationale behind this behavior, so any help would be greatly appreciated.
[fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/harisf/e1wqnfr2/3/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Property [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML#reading_the_html_contents_of_an_element) returns or accepts a serialized HTML or XML.

```
document.getElementById("my-id").innerHTML = "<p>Foo <strong>bar</strong> baz.</p>"
```

will display "Foo **bar** baz." as a text.

If you want to display HTML tags you need to escape `<` to `&lt` and `>` to `&gt` to get `&lt;p&gt;Foo &lt;strong&gt;bar&lt;/strong&gt; baz.&lt;/p&gt;`

You can use this function to do it (taken from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30930653/446792%5D)):

```js
function escapeHTML(html) {
    return document.createElement('div').appendChild(document.createTextNode(html)).parentNode.innerHTML;
}
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, the rationale is that innerHTML transforms some special control-characters (or character-sequences) pairwise to each other (like <div> to &lt;div&gt; and vice-versa) so that a single application of innerHTML grabs the control-interpretation of the sequence, and the regular interpretation is restored only by a *double* application thereof!  And that's a kind of encoding-decoding implied by the phrase "serialized HTML"

Comment: @exp8j I've added a better function to escape HTML.