# Print JSON to screen for use with cut and paste

Tags: javascript, json, escaping, stringify

This is going to sound really ghetto, but I need to print some Javascript to the browser screen so that it can be cut and pasted into another program.

I'm using `JSON.stringify()` from `json2.js`, however, its not escaping characters such as quotes and new lines (",\n) which are actually control parts of a JSON object and need to be escaped.

For example, I'd get strings like this that cause problems when importing into the other program:

```
{
    string_property_01 : "He said "HI"";  // The string terminates after "He said "
}
```

Are there any libraries that I can use to escape all the characters that I need to escape here?

Thanks!

Comment: How do you print it to the screen?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Option #2

```
var g = {
    sampleFunc2 : function (data) {
        var dataAsText = JSON.stringify(data);
        // w jquery
        $('#debugArea').text(dataAsText);
    }
}

// usage... 
g.sampleFunc2({ id: "4", name: "John Smith" });
```

In markup:

```
<textarea id='debugArea' rows='10' cols='50'></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2):

I do the following, its a beautiful hack.

```
var g = {
    sampleFunc : function (data) {
        var dataAsText = JSON.stringify(data);
        var response = prompt('you can copy and paste this', dataAsText);
    }
}

// usage... 
g.sampleFunc({ id: "4", name: "John Smith" });
```

JavaScript prompt... gotta love it.

Comment: Thats a good idea, I wonder if it can handle about 6mb of text though?

Comment: ha... if not... chop it up into peices... I have another suggestion too... will post

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure this isn't just a browser rendering thing playing tricks on you?  A JSON library is going to escape chars properly to give you a valid JSON string.  Have you tried comparing the output of json2.js to the native JSON.stringify some browsers (like chrome) have?

Comment: It looks like I was incorrect about the source of the problem.  The text I was using had html tags in it that were getting rendered, specifically, the <p> tag

Comment: Glad you figured it out.  If you want to display JSON that looks raw (and is valid for copy/paste), you'll want to use <code> or <pre> tags and escape the HTML entities: < becomes &lt; and so forth. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery for one way to do that.