# javascript xss inside textarea

Tags: php, javascript, xss

I have a span where i have this text inside:

```
/><textarea>
```

i then try to edit the span's text by replacing whats inside it with a textarea and adding inside its text.

then, when i try to cancel the edit and remove the textarea and then return the data back to the span, this appears:

/> and the textarea near it.

which is wrong.

i am trying to avoid such things due to xss attacks.

also if i try adding inside the span this code:

```
';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\';alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//\";alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))//--></SCRIPT>">'><SCRIPT>alert(String.fromCharCode(88,83,83))</SCRIPT>
```

to test if xss is working... i will not get any error since i use htmlentities when i refresh the page...

so i use the click button, the textarea appears with this inside... all good here but when i cancel it so i can see the message back as it was inside the span.. the XSS alert popups...

any ideas on how to solve this?

Comment: Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery.  This will allow you to safely insert non-code from a textarea into a span (escaping HTML).  Alternatively, you could use a markup language (like [Markdown](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markdown) with [Markitup](http://markitup.jaysalvat.com/home/)) to allow a user to perform safe-HTML.

Comment: thanks i just had to replace html() which then filled the span with the text with text().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just had to replace html() which then filled the span with the text with text().

Answer (score 0):

Just use text nodes. (`document.createTextNode(text here)` to create it and then `appendChild` it like any other node)