# How to safely get a piece of data into a div tag?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, json, security

I used ajax to download a JSON file from the internet, then set one of the keys to a variable. How do I get the contents of that variable inside a div tag? I could do:

```
theJsonKey = jsonObject.key;  
document.getElementById('theDivTag').innerHTML = theJsonKey;
```

But that doesn't seem safe since someone could put scripts or html in the JSON file.

Comment: use .innerText instead, maybe? That'll prevent the contents from being interpreted as html. Otherwise, if you're willing to use jquery, see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: I thought of that too, but innerText [doesn't work in FF](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t04)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The safest/most cross-browser way might be to do this. *<sup>[createTextNode](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#t01)</sup> <sup>[innerHTML](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_html.html#t03)</sup>*

```
document.getElementById('theDivTag').innerHTML = "";
document.getElementById('theDivTag').appendChild(document.createTextNode(theJsonKey));
```

Credit to Matt McDonald for appendChild :P

<sub><sub><sub>(I should have seen that one)</sub></sub></sub>

Comment: If you're creating a text node, why bother with innerHTML? Just use `Node.appendChild`. innerHTML isn't exactly safe.

Comment: I believe this would return "[object.textnode]" instead of the actual encoded text.

Comment: @LastCoder When I was using innderHTML it did, in which case I changed it to `document.createTextNode(theJsonKey).nodeValue`, which corrected that, but appendChild is much better. See my current answer.

Comment: This seems to work, but it keeps the previous content of the div there. Is there any way to just have the contents of `theJsonKey` in it?

Comment: @Tom at that point you can just call `document.getElementById('theDivTag').innerHTML = "";` just before appending the child.

Comment: This is the best practice method.

Comment: A way to clean up children without innerHTML:
while(element.childNodes[0]) element.removeChild(element.childNodes[0]);

Comment: I saw a similar solution using `.firstChild` but I thought this would be far simpler.

Answer (score 1):

What happens behind the scenes for HTML Encoding.

```
function safeHtml(v) {
    return v.replace(/&/g,'&amp;').replace(/</g,'&lt;').replace(/>/g,'&gt;').replace(/"/g,'&quot;').replace(/'/g, '&apos;');
}
```

& ==> &amp;

> ==> &gt;

< ==> &lt;

" ==> &quot;

' ==> &apos;

For a more complete list for character entities for HTML
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: +1 for encoding strings before injecting them into the DOM. Good idea for preventing script injection attacks! :)