# How to display string having XML data

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, json, datatables

My JSON data is:

```
[
    {
        "serviceName":"test",
        "requestXML":"<soapenvelope><uname>testuser</uname></soapenvelope>"
    },
    {
        "serviceName":"test2",
        "requestXML":"<soapenvelope><uname>testuser2</uname></soapenvelope>"
    } 
]
```

jQuery code to call to backend which returns this JSON data

```
var postRequest = $.post(url);

postRequest.done(function( data ) {

      $('#tableid').dataTable( {
         "processing": true,
          destroy: true,
          "aaData": data,
          "aoColumns": [
                { "data": "serviceName" },
                { "data": "requestXML" },
          ]
      });     
});
```

Now when it is shown on the screen as jQuery DataTable, I wanted the entire XML to be printed as it. But it just prints `testuser` instead of the whole XML.

Could anyone please help me with this as what is going wrong?

I have verified my JSON data is going correctly.

Comment: Because the web page parses it as (invalid) HTML and prints the text.

Comment: How are you printing it?

Comment: In JSP : <table id="tableid" class="display" width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
             <th>SERVICE NAME</th>
                <th>REQUEST XML</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody class="alignCenter">
    </tbody>
     <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th>SERVICE NAME</th>
                <th>REQUEST XML</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
</table>

Comment: Ok, this is the strcture, but how are you entering the data to those fields? via `innerHTML`?

Comment: No, the jquery code posted above automatically does it. I dont have to write any other code for this. $('#tableid').dataTable. Using the tableid mapped with the HTML structure. It does the work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> **SOLUTION**

You can use `$('<div/>').text(data).html()` trick to encode HTML entities.

For example:

```
$('#tableid').dataTable({
    "processing": true,
    "destroy": true,
    "data": data,
    "columns": [
       { 
          "data": "serviceName" 
       },
       { 
          "data": "requestXML",
          "render": function(data, type, full, meta){
              return $('<div/>').text(data).html();
          }
       }
    ]
});
```

> **DEMO**

See [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qnofotaj/) for code and demonstration.

Comment: Super! You made my day! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your server should take care of the response what it is sending. instead of sending

```
[
{"serviceName":"test","requestXML":"<soapenvelope><uname>testuser</uname></soapenvelope>"},
 {"serviceName":"test2","requestXML":"<soapenvelope><uname>testuser2</uname></soapenvelope>"} 
]
```

it should send something like below

```
[
    {"serviceName":"test","requestXML":"&lt;soapenvelope&gt;&lt;uname&gt;testuser&lt;/uname&gt;&lt;/soapenvelope&gt;"},
     {"serviceName":"test2","requestXML":"&lt;soapenvelope&gt;&lt;uname&gt;testuser2&lt;/uname&gt;&lt;/soapenvelope&gt;"} 
    ]
```

If that is not possible ( you don't control the server ) then the following link should help
[Escape markup in JSON-driven jQuery datatable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740567/escape-markup-in-json-driven-jquery-datatable)

Answer (score 0):

First of all you will need XML escaping function (taken from [here](https://gist.github.com/panzi/1857360)):

```
var XML_CHAR_MAP = {
  '<': '&lt;',
  '>': '&gt;',
  '&': '&amp;',
  '"': '&quot;',
  "'": '&apos;'
}

function escapeXml (s) {
  return s.replace(/[<>&"']/g, function (ch) {
    return XML_CHAR_MAP[ch]
  })
}
```

Then you can render cell content using it:

```
{
  data: "requestXML",
  render: function(data, method, object, pos) {
    return '<pre>' + escapeXml(data) + '</pre>'
  }
}
```

Now your XML should be visible. Remove `pre` tags, if not required.

Comment: I tried to use this method. Getting s.replace is not a function. Any clue?