# Jquery gives a Syntax error, unrecognized expression on calling a url including "("

Tags: jquery

i am facing an error in Jquery Load function. I am using jquery to find a string in MySQL database table.
here is a sample of my code.

```
nUrl='count.php?coun='+(code);
$('#memory2').load(nUrl);
```

here, i am using "code" as input. when i use "(" in code like:

```
code = "DQ118 (dq10)";
```

browser gives me an error like:

```
Uncaught Syntax error, unrecognized expression:  (
```

Comment: have you tried using the ascii codes for the brackets  ( = &#40; and ) = &#41;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works pretty fine, look [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ESeF4/). Just maybe try to encode your URI, by using `encodeURIComponent`

```
code = "DQ118 (dq10)";
nUrl='count.php?coun='+encodeURIComponent(code);
```

and use `var` before you declare your variable. For example

```
var code = "DQ118 (dq10)";
var nUrl='count.php?coun='+encodeURIComponent(code);
```

so you avoid declaring your variable globally

Comment: @extremerose71: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Comment: @extremerose71: btw you have virus on very top of your page... be aware of that (iframe)

Comment: thanks for telling me about iframe. i know that. but problem is jquery did not send the string to the server. and gives the error for "(".

Comment: Thanks @genesis for 1st Best and Thanks John for 2nd Best answer.

Answer (score 1):

First of all you must declare the variables ( var code = 'blah'; )

also, "escape" the string:

```
var code = escape("DQ118 (dq10)");
var nUrl = 'count.php?coun='+code;
```

Comment: but i will use your code because it is short and understandable answer.

Comment: @extremerose71: but also wrong. `code` has to be escaped, otherwise you may get strange responses

Answer (score 0):

I've tried it and i don't get that error. In any case you should use encodeURIComponent i think on the code variable

```
code = encodeURIComponent("DQ118 (dq10)");
nUrl='count.php?coun='+code;
$('#example').load(nUrl);
```

Answer (score 0):

follow this previous question on this site [Escaping HTML strings with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery)

it is much clear to understand and help to solve further problems like this..

it works somewhat like this:

```
html.replace(/&/g, "&amp;").replace(/</g, "&lt;").replace(/>/g, "&gt;");
```

Comment: Thanks @Niranjan Kala but i have found a good and short solution form John.