# Sending a class object type through a form submit using $_GET in PHP

Tags: php, class

So I am trying to send an object through the form submit using post. Of course you cannot directly send this data type through so it has to be converted to a string. I have tried with both serialize and json_encode methods but none seem to work.

Because of the structure of my code I would like to try and keep the object. It works when you store all object values into an array -> serialize and then send it through the form. But my question is, is it possible to send the object through? Thanks

index.php

```
<?php

require_once "class.php";

$user1 = new Test("Sam", 18, "coding");

$jsonData = json_encode($user1);

?>

<form action="process.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?= $jsonData; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

process.php

```
<?php

require_once "class.php";

$jsonData = $_GET["data"];

?>
```

class.php

```
<?php 

class Test {
    public $name;
    public $age;
    public $likes;

    function __construct($name, $age, $likes) {
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->age = $age;
        $this->likes = $likes;
    }

    function __get($property) {
        if (property_exists($this, $property)) {
            return $this->$property;
        } else {
            return "Not available";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: https://3v4l.org/lHHXo - you're going to get double-quotes inside the value attribute, which will break your HTML markup. If you know there won't be single-quotes inside the JSON string, you can risk putting the value attribute in single quotes instead...but names can easily include such characters, fairly frequently, so that's probably not realistic.

Comment: `through the form submit using post`...no you're quite clearly using GET, not POST. But certainly POST would make more sense, logically. However that's not the root of the issue

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Put JSON data into html form input hidden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8576339/put-json-data-into-html-form-input-hidden)

Comment: Amazing thank you ADyson. That make sense :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're sending a string containing double quotes `"` as value, which at the end, breaks the HTML :

```
<?php
$data = [ "foo" => "bar" ];

$jsonData = json_encode($data); // '{"foo":"bar"}'

?>

<form action="process.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?= $jsonData; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

Producing the following broken HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="{"foo":"bar"}">
```

You can use [`htmlspecialchars()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) to escape *"any"*<sup>1</sup> HTML characters in a string :

```
<?php
$data = [ "foo" => "bar" ];

$jsonData = htmlspecialchars(json_encode($data)); // {&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}

?>

<form action="process.php" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="data" value="<?= $jsonData; ?>">
    <input type="submit" value="go">
</form>
```

And you get the following HTML :

```
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}">
```

---

To decode it, simply use the reverse function, [`htmlspecialchars_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php) :

```
<?php
$htmlData = $_GET['data']; // '{&quot;foo&quot;:&quot;bar&quot;}'
$jsonData = htmlspecialchars_decode($htmlData]); // '{"foo":"bar"}'
$data = json_decode($jsonData); // [ "foo" => "bar" ]
```

---

<sup>1</sup> *Any* Being only a list of basic characters encoded :

| Character | Replacement |
| --- | --- |
| & (ampersand) | &amp; |
| " (double quote) | &quot;, unless ENT_NOQUOTES is set |
| ' (single quote) | &#039; (for ENT_HTML401) or &apos; (for ENT_XML1, ENT_XHTML or ENT_HTML5), but only when ENT_QUOTES is set |
| < (less than) | &lt; |
| > (greater than) | &gt; |

Comment: Amazing thank you very much Cid, really appreciate the input and extra detail to help me understand. I have managed to get it working which is great, however the object values that are 'protected' compared to 'public' are not being sent across. Is there a way round this too? Thanks

Comment: @RishV json_encode only encodes public properties of an object. I think this is documented. You could try using php serialisation instead.

Comment: @RishV if you want to pass datas from a page to another one, you might want to consider using sessions. If you want to use a form and pass datas that can be retrieved in DB, you can put IDs in hidden input