# XML sanitization and reverse satinization in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

This is probably a very simple question but it's several hours that I'm searching for a satisfying answer and haven't found any:

I am getting a string from the user but I want to sanitize and show it in an alert. The best I could come up with is to write the following function:

```
/**
 * This function replaces XML character entities. '&', '<' and '>' with '&amp;', '&lt;' and '&gt;' respectively.
 */
function sanitize ( str ) {
    if ( !str ) {
        return str;
    }
    return str.replace( '&', '&amp;' ).replace( '<', '&lt;').replace( '>', '&gt;');
}
```

It works. But the question is:

**Isn't there any standard function in Javascript to sanitize a string more efficiently or natively?** (I'm concerned about Chrome and Firefox)

Note: I've searched StackOverflow and threads like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164164/how-to-escape-or-replace-in-xml-file-using-jquery) are not my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Would escape and unescape help you?

```
return escape(str);
```

Comment: Hmm, maybe my answer is not right - I guess it depends on what you want to do with the string. Your code suggests you want to use xml entities. IE. & becomes &amp; etc. My suggestion of using escape turn & into &#38; This might not be what you want?

Comment: Agreed Alex. Like I said, I guess it depends on what you are trying to do downstream with the sanitized string.