# how to assign apostrophe character to a html data attribute value?

Tags: jquery

Step 1 -

I use a post method to return data values and the data values may return apostrophe character and assign the value to a variable. For example,

```
var returnData = "Test's failure";
```

Step 2 -

Next, I attempt to assign the variable to the value of a data type like this:

```
$("testList").append("<li data-test='"+ returnData +"'>" + test_List + " </li>);
```

Summary -

When using firebug to view the value for the variable returnData placed in the attribute data-test, it shows the value of Test and 's failure is not added. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: You need to escape your HTML. See here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Comment: please note that `$("testList")` selects nothing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to be on the safe side:

```
$("<li />").data("test", returnData).html(test_List).appendTo("#testList");
```

Or if you need the attribute:

```
$("<li />", {
    "data-test" : returnData
}).html(test_List).appendTo("#testList");​
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/ZyMCk/