# remove HTML from input jquery

Tags: jquery

If i get the .val() from a text input, how can I make sure there is no HTML in there and just plain text?

I am writing a small chat program but I dont want users to be able to enter HTML.

Comment: You could use jQuery, `$("<div>" + $(input).val() + "</div>").text()`, or you could use a regexp.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strip HTML from Text JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/822452/strip-html-from-text-javascript)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it by getting the textContent of the HTML they enter:

```
// Get the value of the input
var inputText = $('#my-input').val();
// Store only the text and no HTML elements.
inputText = $(inputText)[0].textContent;
```

Here is an example:

http://jsfiddle.net/thom801/5A3sQ/1/

Comment: aah brilliant - any thoughts on how to leave only **certain** tags? like bold and italics?

Comment: You would probably need to learn some regex at that point. It would be really difficult I think. Maybe a WYSIWYG editor would work well for what you are doing? There are some really lightweight ones.

Comment: Well. You could use a combination of .html() and .each too to whitelist tags. It will get a little complicated when the tags are nested but not impossible.

Comment: Hi, good solution but... it seems that it does not run if value is plain text without html... it generates errors. Instead a code like `inputText = inputText.replace(/<\/?[^>]+(>|$)/g, "");` seems running correctly