# Text containing & given to jquery ajax causing error in the postvariable?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, html-entities

I have a Text box and am just checking the availability of the text using jqueryAjax. Am facing a Issue like when am checking for a text containing `&`  the Post Variables in the jquery I checked for the solution which was given in the [Stack overflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18750001/782145) but still in that when we take the html encoded value for `&` it gives `&#38;` which will again have `&` and as a result  the jquery ajax post variable gets broken. the code i tried is given below

```
    //from the text field
    var textfieldValue=$('#text').val();

    //Jquery Ajax
    $.ajax({
       type: "POST",
       async: false,
       url: "ajax/CheckAvailabilityphppage.php",
       data: "fieldvalue="+textfieldValue,
       dataType: "json",
       success: function(data){
         if (data['Status'] == 'YES'){
           alert('yes its Available');
          }else{
           alert('Sorry Not Available');
          }
       }
   });
```

In the Firebug the Post Variables are shown as (if the text is P&P)

```
P   
fieldvalue P
```

The `&P` is taking as an another Post Parameter and as a result the ajax is only validating the text `P`

Any Help or suggestions are much Appreciated.

Thanks a Lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pass an object to the data parameter and jquery will automagically encode it for you.

```
data: { fieldvalue: textfieldValue },
```

Comment: To be fair, CBroe's method should have worked if this one did. `data: "fieldvalue="+encodeURIComponent(textfieldValue),`

Answer (score 1):

You need to URL-encode the value properly.

Use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) for that.

Comment: no sorry I tried.. it won't work.. It won't encode &.

Comment: When i Print the value after encoding in Firebug i am getting `%2525255Bobject%25252520HTMLInputElement%2525255D` for the text `P&P` Am I wrong somewhere..??

Comment: @PhilemonphilipKunjumon that suggests you're missing the `.val()` portion of the code in your question.

Comment: Can you please explain that a bit more. If the. Val() portion is missed out then when I do console.log(textfieldValue) I am getting the value in the text field...