# Javascript API to convert comma separated string to HTML

Tags: javascript

I have a list of countries separated by comma like

```
Abnaki,Achinese,Achumawi,African,Afrikaans,Ahtena,Alabama,Albanian,Aleut,Algonquian,American Indian,American Sign Language
```

Now I want to convert this string in HTML format like this

```
<option value="Abnaki">Abnaki</option><option value="Achinese">Achinese</option><option value="Achumawi">Achumawi</option><option value="African">African</option><option value="Afrikaans">Afrikaans</option><option value="Ahtena">Ahtena</option><option value="Alabama">Alabama</option><option value="Albanian">Albanian</option><option value="Aleut">Aleut</option><option value="Algonquian">Algonquian</option><option value="American Indian" selected="selected">American Indian</option>
```

Is there any javascript API available to do this transformation which will also take care of special characters in the countries supplied

Comment: There is not such API but i believe if you try you can accomplise this with plain javacript.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using the [split](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function and creating DOM elements manually:

```
var countryCsv = 'Abnaki,Achinese,Achumawi';

var countries = countryCsv.split(',');

for (var i = 0; i < countries.length; i++)
{
    var option = document.createElement('option');
    option.text = countries[i];
    option.value = countries[i];
    select.appendChild(option);
}
```

Comment: Here's a fiddle that shows how to do just what you show above.  http://jsfiddle.net/ymXhA/

Answer (score 1):

You didn't specify if you want a DOM tree or a string, but if you'd prefer a string my solution would be

```
'Abnaki,Achinese,Achumawi,African'.split(',').map(function(c) { 
  return '<option value="' + c + '">' + c + '</option>';
}).join('');
```

For replacing special characters (not strictly necessary depending on the encoding of your html) take a look at [Encode html entities in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18749591/encode-html-entities-in-javascript).