# Getting HTML to look like HTML on a web page

Tags: javascript, html

On Stack overflow you can use ctrl k to make HTML look like HTML and not the output of it.

So something like

```
<div>
    <p>Hello world</p>
</div>
```

Instead of Hello World

I inspected the web page and it comes out like this

```
<pre>
  <code>
    &lt;div&gt;
    &lt;p&gt;Hello world&lt;/p&gt;
    &lt;/div&gt;
  </code>
</pre>
```

I am working on a project where I want to do something similar. I'm assuming it uses some some javascript function to perform this but I'm not really sure, anyone know how this works?

Comment: The cause of this is going to depend on the technology that was used. Please provide a link to the problem, or at least more context. How was the HTML added to the page? Did you type it in or was it rendered by some server-side technology?

Comment: `<pre>` is for pre-formatted text. If you want to display markup in the `<pre>` you need to convert the markup to entities as per your example. You can either do it manually or through scripting JS or php. `html_entites(str)` in php

Comment: This link is also relevant http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820453/display-html-code-in-html

Comment: Use HTML Entities in `<pre>` tag/s:   http://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html  Note: You should add a 0 before anything like `#39;`. So it's `#039;` which would be PHP `htmlentities()` compatible. The Entity Name should be used whenever possible, as in `&lt;`, `&gt;`, and `&quot;`, for compatibility reasons.

Comment: You could do this in PHP by adding header("Content-type: text/plain"), which will force the browser to render the rest of the page content as plaintext.

Answer (score 0):

If you have support for PHP you could use the function [htmlentities()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php).

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, you can use `string.replace()` to achieve the same.

For example:

```
var string = '<h1> Hello </h1>'
console.log(string.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;'));
// "&lt;h1&gt; Hello &lt;/h1&gt;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that HTML has to be Html-encoded in order to see the brackets. The < symbol is encoded as &lt; (less than), while the > symbol is encoded as &gt; (greater than).

So the question is how do you do that automatically without having to remember to do it.

You may want to check out syntax highlighter:

Syntax Highlighter: http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/

You can also use the string replace and write your own function as sarbbottam suggests.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
function preIt(code){
    code = code.replace(/[&<>]/g, function(tag){
        return {'<' : '&lt;', '>' : '&gt;', '&' : '&amp;'}[tag];
    });
    return "<pre>"+code+"</pre>";
}
```

Usage:

```
document.write(preIt("<div><p>Hello world!</p></div>"));
```

The function takes `HTML` code as its input and then performs a [`RegEx`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) replace on the code. It uses a callback function to replace the matched characters with the appropriate [`HTML` entity code](http://dev.w3.org/html5/html-author/charref).

Alternatively, you could implement the [code in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18750001/1336653).

Answer (score 0):

StackOverflow is merely moving the selected lines over using 4 spaces when you select lines within the `<textarea>` element, which then is used as markup that can be detected via JavaScript. It would look something like the following:

```
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="myTextarea" style="width:500px;height:400px;"></textarea>
<button id="clickme">Click me!</button>

<script>
    $('#clickme').on('click', function() {
        var value = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value.replace(/(\n|^)[ ]{4}([^\n]*)/g, function(c) {
            // console.log('found! c ==', c, '; arguments ==', arguments);

            var lineData = arguments[2];

            return "<pre><code>" + lineData.replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;') + "</code></pre>";
        });

        // console.log('value ==', value);

        $('body').append(value);
    });
</script>
```

In the `<textarea>` place text such as the following, making sure that 4 spaces lead before each line that needs to be formatted as displayable HTML:

```
<div>
    Hello world!<br />
</div>
```

Then finally click the "Click me!" button. jQuery was used in this code example for brevity.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up using the .html() method of jquery to format the html

```
$( "p" ).click(function() {
  var htmlString = $( this ).html();
  $( this ).text( htmlString );
});
```

here's the documentation
http://api.jquery.com/html/

and a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/arh6E/