# How to write tags as strings using document.write()?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to write tags as  strings using document.write()?

```
var myWindow= window.open('', '', 'width=500, height=500');
document.write("<h1> Hello! </h1>"
```

This would write Hello! but the ouput I desire is ->   Hello! with the tags `<h1>` and `</h1>`.

Comment: Sure, just do it the same way you do it in HTML (because that's what you pass to `document.write`).

Comment: I want the tags to be displayed too.

Comment: I understand that. If you want to display "tags" in HTML, you have to use HTML entities. E.g.: `&lt;h1&gt;` (http://jsfiddle.net/43r5nLms/)

Comment: Encode the string. Why are you using `document.write` instead of `document.body.innerHTML` (or in this case `document.body.textContent`, when you actually wouldn't have to encode the string)? You also probably want something like `myWindow.document.body.textContent = '<h1> Hello! </h1>';`

Comment: Probably also worth mentioning: http://stackoverflow.com/a/23834738/451969

Comment: @JaredFarrish—so why use *innerHTML* instead of *document.write*? A new window (per the OP) does not have a document or body to insert *innerHTML* into, so *document.write* is entirely appropriate, though it should include a valid document (which only requires a *title* element in addition to a block element), not just a snippet.

Comment: @RobG - Ok, tell me why [this works](http://jsfiddle.net/ugL2d9tk/1) (link edited).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set the `textContent` property of the body, it knows it is text and not HTML (so it will encode the characters for you):

```
document.body.textContent = '<h1> Hello! </h1>`
```

Otherwise:

```
document.body.innerHTML = '&gt;h1&lt; Hello! &gt;/h1&lt;';
```

Comment: You could do the same thing as the second with `document.body.innerHTML`, without using the antiquated `document.write()`.

Comment: "[textContent] will encode the characters for you"—no, it won't. The [*W3C DOM 3 Core*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) states "*…on setting, no parsing is performed either, the input string is taken as pure textual content.*" In other words, the characters are left as–is, they just aren't parsed as content.

Comment: @RobG: no, the innerHTML is different, and html codes have replaced hard-coded entities. contrast to a pure reflective property like textarea's .value...

Comment: @dandavis—On setting, *innerHTML* must parse the text as markup, on getting it must generate markup that when inserted (and parsed) restores the original markup. So encoding is required to mask markup (e.g. `<` becomes `&lt;` or similar). The *textContent* property does neither. The text is not parsed, it's placed in the document exactly as–is. The same on getting, it gets exactly the text that is in the document and ignores all markup (per the 10 year old [*referenced specification*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent), which all browsers I tested comply with).