# Function for escaping quotes in javascript?

Tags: javascript, php, quotes

Is there a function in JavaScript that does the same as `htmlentities($string, ENT_QUOTES)` in PHP? I searched a lot but couldnt find it, everyone recommending regex.

Just wanted to make sure there was no other easier way before I try that

Comment: http://webdesignfan.com/htmlspecialchars-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

see this [tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/javascript/htmlentities-for-javascript/)

it's a 'port' of PHP's htmlentities function:

```
function htmlEntities(str) {
    return String(str).replace(/&/g, '&amp;').replace(/</g, '&lt;').replace(/>/g, '&gt;').replace(/"/g, '&quot;');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's PHP.js's implementation of that: http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities/

```
function htmlentities(string, quote_style, charset, double_encode) {
  //  discuss at: http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities/
  // original by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //  revised by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  //  revised by: Kevin van Zonneveld (http://kevin.vanzonneveld.net)
  // improved by: nobbler
  // improved by: Jack
  // improved by: Rafał Kukawski (http://blog.kukawski.pl)
  // improved by: Dj (http://phpjs.org/functions/htmlentities:425#comment_134018)
  // bugfixed by: Onno Marsman
  // bugfixed by: Brett Zamir (http://brett-zamir.me)
  //    input by: Ratheous
  //  depends on: get_html_translation_table
  //   example 1: htmlentities('Kevin & van Zonneveld');
  //   returns 1: 'Kevin &amp; van Zonneveld'
  //   example 2: htmlentities("foo'bar","ENT_QUOTES");
  //   returns 2: 'foo&#039;bar'

  var hash_map = this.get_html_translation_table('HTML_ENTITIES', quote_style),
    symbol = '';
  string = string == null ? '' : string + '';

  if (!hash_map) {
    return false;
  }

  if (quote_style && quote_style === 'ENT_QUOTES') {
    hash_map["'"] = '&#039;';
  }

  if ( !! double_encode || double_encode == null) {
    for (symbol in hash_map) {
      if (hash_map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
        string = string.split(symbol)
          .join(hash_map[symbol]);
      }
    }
  } else {
    string = string.replace(/([\s\S]*?)(&(?:#\d+|#x[\da-f]+|[a-zA-Z][\da-z]*);|$)/g, function(ignore, text, entity) {
      for (symbol in hash_map) {
        if (hash_map.hasOwnProperty(symbol)) {
          text = text.split(symbol)
            .join(hash_map[symbol]);
        }
      }

      return text + entity;
    });
  }

  return string;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript doesn't have any convenient functions for generating escaped HTML.

Escaping data for HTML in JavaScript is usually done using DOM methods and avoiding mashing together strings of HTML altogether.

```
element.setAttribute("data-foo", 'Example value with a " in it');
```

In most cases where converting text to a string of HTML is required (i.e. putting it in the current document is not the end goal), the work around is to create a div element, then use DOM methods on it, then read the `innerHTML` property of the div.

Answer (score 0):

You might be looking for this

```
var encodedStr = rawStr.replace(/[\u00A0-\u9999<>\&]/gim, function(i) {
   return '&#'+i.charCodeAt(0)+';';
});
```

Note, that

> This code will replace all characters in the given range (unicode 00A0 - 9999, as well as ampersand, greater & less than) with their html entity equivalents, which is simply &#nnn; where nnn is the unicode value we get from charCodeAt. <sup>[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18750001/1828051)</sup>